# How to convert DateTime from JSON to C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, silverlight-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert UNIX timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

I've got the following class:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class TestClass
{
  [DataMemberAttribute]
  public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the JSON:

```
{ "MyDateTime":"1221818565" }
```

The JSON is being returned from a PHP webservice.

What I need to do, is convert that epoch string into a valid C# DateTime. What's the best way of doing this?

I can do this:

```
[IgnoreDataMemberAttribute]
public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }

[DataMemberAttribute(Name = "MyDateTime")]
public Int32 MyDateTimeTicks
{
  get { return this.MyDateTime.Convert(...); }
  set { this.Created = new DateTime(...); }
}
```

But the trouble with this is, the MyDateTimeTicks is public (changing it to private causes an exception in the serialization process)

Comment: why do you care if MyDateTimeTicks is public?

Comment: Because it's all part of the software contract. I don't want to expose any extra members than I have to - and it helps if those members are in a useful format for me to use (i.e. DateTime vs number / ticks).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finishing what you posted, AND making it private seemed to work fine for me.

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClass
{

    private static readonly DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "MyDateTime")]
    private int MyDateTimeTicks
    {
        get { return (int)(this.MyDateTime - unixEpoch).TotalSeconds; }
        set { this.MyDateTime = unixEpoch.AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(value)); }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that in Silverlight or .net / WPF?

Comment: it's standard .net wcf.  should work in either

Comment: Why is your code in the setter `Convert.ToInt32(value)` and not just `value` -- it's already an `int`, right?

Answer (score 7):

```
private DateTime ConvertJsonStringToDateTime(string jsonTime)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonTime) && jsonTime.IndexOf("Date") > -1)
            {
                string milis = jsonTime.Substring(jsonTime.IndexOf("(") + 1);
                string sign = milis.IndexOf("+") > -1 ? "+" : "-";
                string hours = milis.Substring(milis.IndexOf(sign));
                milis = milis.Substring(0, milis.IndexOf(sign));
                hours = hours.Substring(0, hours.IndexOf(")"));
                return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(milis)).AddHours(Convert.ToInt64(hours) / 100);                 
            }

            return DateTime.Now;
        }
```

Comment: Is this better than the other answers?

Comment: Thanks! Work for me!

Comment: Nope, not working, if datetime string without timezone = System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I've come up with.  In C#, it looks like you need to create a new DateTime and add the epoch value as 'seconds' to this DateTime.  Here's what it looks like in code:

```
new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(1221818565);
```

When using the Visual Studio immediate window, I printed the result of this operation to the debugger console:

```
{9/19/2008 10:02:45 AM}
    Date: {9/19/2008 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 19
    DayOfWeek: Friday
    DayOfYear: 263
    Hour: 10
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 2
    Month: 9
    Second: 45
    Ticks: 633574153650000000
    TimeOfDay: {10:02:45}
    Year: 2008
```

Comment: You should also specify DateTimeKind.Utc.

Answer (score 4):

I know your question was for PHP, but I just wanted to note a "gotcha" for .NET JSON: it appears that .NET gives you the date in "milliseconds since epoch" (as opposed to seconds). In this case, the AddSeconds line should be:
`unixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(Int64.Parse(date));`

More info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2008/03/05/system-datetime-ticks-vs-json-date.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the following:

```
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime dotnetTime = unixEpoch.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(ticks));
```

where `ticks` is the value passed to you by PHP.