# C# strange with DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I got some strange result for:

```
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(1296346155).ToString());
```

Result is:

> 01.01.0001 0:02:09

But it is not right!

I parsed value 1296346155 from some file. It said that it is in UTC;

Please explain;)

Thank you for help!)))

Comment: It may be a Unix time. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Comment: What was some file? I am guessing it was in WIN32 FileTime which uses January 1, 1601 (UTC) as its offset, not Jan 1, 0001.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DateTime expects "A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar." (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx))

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa) shows how you can convert a unix timestamp to a DateTime.

Answer (score 4):

The constructor for DateTime that accept `long` type is expecting `ticks` value, not seconds or even milliseconds, and not from `1/1/1970` like in other languages.

So 1296346155 ticks [is 129 seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tickspersecond.aspx).

Comment: Which is 2 minutes and 9 Seconds :-)

Answer (score 3):

If it's Unix time, then the following should yield the expected result;

```
DateTime baseTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(baseTime.AddSeconds(1296346155));
```

See [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

That constructor is not what you want as the time is not measured in ticks.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0);
start = start.AddSeconds(1296346155).ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine(start);  
// You don't need to use ToString() in a Console.WriteLine call
```

Answer (score 2):

That is correct - what were you expecting it to be and why?

The constructor [System.DateTime(Int64)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) takes the number of 100-nanosecond intervals (known as Ticks) since January 1st 0001 (in the Gregorian calendar).

Therefore, 1296346155 / 10000000 gives you the number of seconds, which is 129.6.

Therefore, this should display 2 minutes and 9 seconds since midnight on 1st January 0001.

Answer (score 2):

Ive found the following subject where there is a conversion between unix timestamp (the one you have) and .Net DateTime

[How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)