# Mysql TimeStamp datatype

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am developing a asp.net web application with ado.net entity framework and MySQL as backend.
I have taken some columns in DB as timestamp datatype when I get date from DB these fields of timestamp datatype returns null. In application these fields are mapped as datetimeoffset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert UNIX timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

See the accepted answer to this post

[How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

You need to adapt the timestamps into datetimeoffset objects in .net.

Comment: Thanks for reply

the prb is that date is saving properly in valid format only when i access data it return null

Comment: Yes, I know.  I think you need to adapt the timestamp from the database into a datetimeoffset.