# Is Unix time the value of a MYSQL timestamp data type? Correct code example to convert from C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, timestamp

I found this sample source code for C# from [How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa):

DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 4, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0);

DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

TimeSpan span = (date - epoch);

double unixTime =span.TotalSeconds.Dump();

If I was to insert into a MYSQL table the value of unixTime, would this be equivalent of a MYSQL timestamp datatype value? I just want to confirm this.

Comment: Can you post an example of what `unixTime` looks like? I don't know offhand what `Dump` does.

Comment: Sorry, I think unixTime should be double unixTime =span.TotalSeconds;

Comment: I think you should also create the start of Epoch in UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of MySQL. TIMESTAMP field format has been changed from unixtime to dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss from 5.something. If you want to insert a unixtime into a timestamp field, you should use FROM_UNIXTIME() builtin.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful but the question becomes could I pass to MYSQL's FROM_UNIXTIME(the value of unixTime) which is from the C# example above? I just want ensure my logic is correct.

Comment: Should work from what I understand. Isn't it easier to just test? Insert a date and then do select from_unixtime(field) from table_you_inserted_it_to; ? :)