# Datetime format from UNIX epoch

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert UNIX timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

I use this code to get the format datetime of a given UNIX epoch

```
DateTime epoch=new DateTime(1970,1,1);
DateTime dt=new DateTime(1325506582751000+epoch.Ticks());
```

The output result is 1975/x/y

which is incorrect.

Is the epoch incorrectly defined ? How can I get the correct one from any given datetime data ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public DateTime FromUnixTime(long unixTime)
{
    var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return epoch.AddSeconds(unixTime);
}
```

or you can read this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/timestamp.aspx).