# Convert Date to Milliseconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, highcharts

I am working with Visual Studio 2010, MVC 3 and C#.  I am creating some highcharts and need to have the x-axis be a date.  I am pulling the dates from a database and adding them to and array that will then be passed to highcharts.  I think highcharts requires the dates to be in millisecond format.  Ho do I go about converting a DateTime of '12/20/2011 5:10:13 PM" for example to milliseconds?

Comment: Do you mean you need the `DateTime` value in Unix epoch format, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700823/datetime-format-from-unix-epoch)?

Comment: What do you mean by millisecond format? The number of milliseconds elapsed since the Unix epoch? Since 01/01/0001?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Once you figure out what you want to calculate milliseconds from, you can just take one DateTime object from another to get a TimeSpan object. From TimeSpan you can get TotalMilliseconds.

In other words, if start and end are DateTime objects, you can do this:

```
double milliseconds = (end - start).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: I am not quite sure yet what I want to calculate milliseconds from.  I just know that I can't pass a DateTime object to HighCharts.  For data it only accepts Number values.  I tested your solution out and it appears to work.  I received a couple of acceptable answers.  However, I think yours is the cleanest and easiest to use.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) property and convert the value to milliseconds.

> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001, which represents DateTime.MinValue. It does not include the number of ticks that are attributable to leap seconds.
>
> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

Answer (score 7):

The `.Ticks` in C# `DateTime` gives you the value of any time in ticks. You can thereafter convert to milliseconds as shown below:

```
long dateticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
long datemilliseconds = dateticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
```

Comment: Please test your code before you post. I fixed simple errors in your code.

Comment: The correct way to do this would be `long datemilliseconds = dateticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;`. Don't use magic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime[] dates = ;

var minDate = dates.Min();

var msDates = dates.Select(date => (date - minDate).TotalMilliseconds).ToArray();
```

Comment: This was my assumption as well that a minimum reference date is required.