# convert system datatime to milliseconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, formatting

My input is `12/26/2013 12:19:47 PM`

My output format is `1388078387000`.

I am using [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm) to convert datetime to milliseconds.

please give me answer.

Comment: what exactly you want?? you want to convert datetime to miliseconds????

Comment: hi... my requirement is convert datetime to milliseconds...?

Comment: you can try workaround like dateTime.Subtract(new DateTime(0)).TotalMilliseconds

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Date to Milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724246/convert-date-to-milliseconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of

```
(DateTime.Now - DateTime.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds;
```

here inplace of `DateTime.Now` you can take your date. and you can easily find total miliseconds

Comment: hi i write this code my out put is 63523658266487.7 but i am using http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm site different format that is 1388078387000   please help me which once is correct....?

Comment: yah then you can change the DateTime.MinValue to your starting value. So that it will give you answer that you need

Comment: Thanku very much .....

Comment: @RavinderReddy- if you got it as your answer then please tick this answer as your correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
long milliseconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks
```

or

```
long milliseconds = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
```