# New to Json/Java - what datatype is this? A datetime? 13 digits long. Using PHP

Tags: java, php, json, date, types

I'm experimenting/learning with java and json. I'm trying to make my own data for a json parser and I can't figure out what datatype the example data it gives me is. I think it's a datetime, but I don't know how to get my date (regular format) to the json date format. I'm coding the example using PHP.

Jsonp Example Data:

```
[1110844800000,178.61],
[1110931200000,175.60],
[1111017600000,179.29],
```

My Date and Data format:

```
2012-03-01 18:21:31,42
2012-03-01 18:22:31,46
2012-03-02 18:21:31,40
```

Does anyone know if the 13 digit date/time json above is a datetime specific to java or json? And if so, how to get my data to that format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like the Javascript version of [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is really just Unix time in milliseconds rather than seconds.

Divide your 13-digit numbers by 1000 and run them through this site to verify: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Answer (score 7):

Each of what you've quoted is an array with two entries. The first entry in each array *might* be a datetime. If so:

```
1110844800000 = Tue, 15 Mar 2005 00:00:00 GMT
1110931200000 = Wed, 16 Mar 2005 00:00:00 GMT
1111017600000 = Thu, 17 Mar 2005 00:00:00 GMT
```

JavaScript stores date/times as milliseconds since The Epoch (midnight on 1 Jan 1970 GMT), so to convert to `Date` instances:

```
var dt = new Date(1110844800000);
```

...which is how I got the values above.

No idea what the second entry in each array is. It looks like a currency (money) figure.

Answer (score 1):

‘-1110844800000’ is number of milliseconds from January 1, 1970 and ‘-178.61’ is time offset.

Answer (score 0):

Your first array is Unix Time in milliseconds like gregheo said.

If you want to convert your Unix timestamp in JAVA, you can find a good example there :

[Convert UNIX Timestamp to DT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)