# What datetime format is a number like "22194885"?

Tags: c#

I have a very simple issue with datetime and am seeking some help.

I have a log that I would like to get all data information from. There are three columns of datetime formats (2 in UNIX timestamp while the other isn't).

The one with different timestamp format offers a value of, for example, `22194885` which I don't know which datetime type it belongs to.

Comment: Its probably ticks in the number of milliseconds since January 1970 or something...or maybe not....you already understand everything here right: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply but that is not true, the miliseconds from the 1970 must be larger, while the above number is still small.

Comment: @Jason naw, `22194885` in ms is only `Thu Jan 01 1970 01:09:54 GMT-0500 (EST)`; even in seconds it's still only `Mon Sep 14 1970 17:14:45 GMT-0400 (EDT)`.

Comment: @Jason `getTime()` of `Date` object in `JavaScript` would give milliseconds time from 1970 but I think its not in C#

Comment: How much does the number increment by between log entries?  Can you correlate two specific numbers in that format to a specific real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like minutes since January 1, 1970.  this is Python code, but works the same as C localtime():

```
>>> import time
>>> time.localtime(22194885*60)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=19, tm_min=45, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=73, tm_isdst=1)
```

Works out to 3/13/2012 7:45pm.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be minutes since the Epoch, rather than milliseconds

22194885 minutes / 60 = 369914.75 hours

369914.75 hours / 24 = 15413.1 days

15413.1 days / 365 = 42.2 years

1970 + 42.2 = about today

For help converting Epoch time to .Net time, see

[How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Remember that question deals with milliseconds, so you'll have to adjust the answer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the calculations in Eric J's answer (which has been deleted), this could well be the number of minutes since the epoch.  Bah!  He slipped in a ninja edit.

Julian seconds (since the start of the year) is also a strong possibility.

Comment: Yeah, sorry Ben.  My first calculation was backwards therefore counterintuitive, and I also had a typo stating seconds rather than minutes.

Comment: "Julian seconds"... let's hope not...  A year 2000 problem once every year ;-)