# Convert DateTime Without Adjusting for Time Zone

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using the jQuery FullCalendar control and populating a hidden field with the calendar events in a JSON string.

To accomplish this I have to convert the date/times.
The example function I found below passes them in a usable format.
However, it's adjusting the events based on the client time zone.

How do I modify the function below to convert a SQL datetime without adjusting for the client time zone?

I tried removing ToUniversalTime() as suggested on another post, but it throws the time WAY off.

```
private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
   long epoch = (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
   return epoch;
}
```

Comment: How are you communicating with SQL that it needs a `long`?  Which flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert UNIX timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

I would try `STRING newstring = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", yourdatevar);` , and make sure the format is the one that you need for the SQL Datetime(I beleive that's it though).

Comment: I think you're gonna wanna check that argument you passed to `.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following which will format the date in to a long data time, this should stop any confusion with clients and different culture settings.

```
.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff")
```