# How to generate a UTC Unix Timestamp in C#

Tags: c#, date, time, unix-timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert UNIX timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

How can I create a unix timestamp in C#? (e.g.  2012-10-10 14:00:00 -> 1349877600)

Comment: Funny to see a question marked as a duplicate...multiple times. :)

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Converting-Unix-Timestamps-to-DateTime-and-Vice-Versa-in-C-

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
private double ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    //create Timespan by subtracting the value provided from
    //the Unix Epoch
    TimeSpan span = (value - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());

    //return the total seconds (which is a UNIX timestamp)
    return (double)span.TotalSeconds;
}
```

Comment: Why "double"?  Wouldn't a long integer be a better model for seconds? (And more consistent with the Unix representation?)

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard If you want a `long`, I suggest `return span.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;`. However, since 2015, the BCL has a built in method, `((DateTimeOffset)value).ToUnixTimeSeconds()`.

Answer (score -1):

`DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(2012,10,10,14,0,0)).TotalSeconds`

Comment: A) You're missing a paren, I'm assuming it should go before `DateTime.UtcNow`, yes?  And shouldn't `new DateTime(2012,10,10,14,0,0)` be the Unix epoch 1/1/1970?