# MVC how to convert date time into unix timestrap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I would like to know how to convert date time into unix timestrap? Could you show me an example please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa/250400#250400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for: [How to convert UNIX timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/250400/968633)

Further urls from a google search yeild:

[Working with DateTime and Unix Time Stamps or Universal time (UTC) in C#](http://www.rhyous.com/2009/09/30/working-with-unix-time-stamps-or-universal-time-utc-in-csharp/)

[C# converting DateTime to UNIX timestamp and vice versa](http://abouteverythingandnothing.info/2011/08/cshar-converting-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-and-vice-versa/)