# Convert ticks to unix timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I m getting start time `634942626000000000` and end time `634942638000000000`. How can I convert it to a Unix timestamp? I want to display formatted date/time in PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C# ticks is a number of ticks since midnight `0001-01-01 00:00:00` (every tick is 1/10000000 of second) and UNIX timestamp is number of seconds since beginning of the UNIX epoch (`1970-01-01 01:00:00`), so desired result is `$seconds = 634942626000000000/10000000 - $number_of_seconds`, where `$number_of_seconds` is seconds between `0001-00-01 00:00:00` and `1970-01-01 01:00:00`. So, all you need now is to determine what `$number_of_seconds` is equals.

**Update:** this is how to do it in C# : [How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

**Update 2** Using this simple script http://hastebin.com/lefiyiheju.mel determined that `$number_of_seconds` is 62136892800, but I don't know if it is much accurate

Comment: 6.214×10^10 seconds is the result wolfram alpha gives. for number of seconds between 0001 and 1970 however that is not accurate enough for the kind of calculation he is looking for.

Comment: May be this can be done using C# + bigint, because it calculates time from `0001-01-01 00:00:00` everywhere, but I don't know C# language

Comment: Thanks a lot for detail reply..I really appreciate it.

Comment: I've calculated $number_of_seconds = 62135600400. And this seems to be accurate up to seconds, which is good enough for what I want to use it for.

Comment: `Math.floor(numOfTicks/10000 - 62136892800000)` // JS timestamp (ms)

`new Date(Math.floor(numOfTicks/10000 - 62136892800000))` // js Date

Comment: Isn't your UNIX epoch off by 1 hour? from what i found, Unix Timestamp 0 is equal to: 621355968000000000 Ticks. Shouldn't $num_of_secs be 621355968000000000/10000000 ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$seconds = 634942626000000000 / 1000000000;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $seconds);
```

Comment: I tried but returns 1969-12-31 19:32:49. it must be current today date/time. I m getting it from http://122.155.1.10/program-info/pginfo-20130120.txt

Comment: Yes, I already fixed it. still i get 1969-12-31 19:32:49 . Any suggestion?

Comment: Ticks count from 0001-01-01, Unix time stamps count from 1970-01-01, so this answer is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

In Python, you'll do

```
In [53]: import datetime

In [54]: ticks = 634942626000000000

In [55]: start = datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1)

In [56]: delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=ticks/10000000)

In [57]: the_actual_date = start + delta

In [58]: the_actual_date.timestamp()
Out[58]: 1358665800.0

In [59]: the_actual_date
Out[59]: datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 20, 7, 10)
```