# Convert Unix Timestamp to .net int64 datetime

Tags: php, .net, date, unix-timestamp, int64

First of all, I know that it's duplicate, but those questions aren't what I am looking for.

I'm using an API to add participants in an online application. When I post JSON object to endpoint, everything is posted except dates. There's some misunderstanding with date format. If I get existing participants and check the date format that's this:

```
{
   "participant":{  
      "ID":201954,
         //  Long Object
      "DateOfBirth":"\/Date(857305424000-0500)\/",
   }
}
```

I figured out that first 9 char are UNIX timestamp but rest of them?? not sure. Any idea what is this format?

**EDIT**
Online application is made in .net/asp/c# not sure about them. But I am writing my code in php application which post json object via cURL

**EDIT 2**
I checked parsing wrong formats and got this error:

> The value '0.48631700 1425319593' cannot be parsed as the type
>   'Int64'.'. Please see InnerException for more details.

Any idea how can I get the format of .net's int64 datetime in php?

Comment: Downvote after a year? seriously? Any reason why and who did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON itself [does not specify how dates should be formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format), so you need to know the requirements of the target .NET application. Most likely it makes sense to [convert to a "readable" date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040291/converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-formatted-date-string)

Example (php):

```
$timestamp=1333699439;
echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp); 
// outputs 2012-04-06T08:03:59Z
```

Example (.net):

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParse("2012-04-06T08:03:59Z", out d); 
// receives 4/6/2012 8:03:59 AM (in US-format)
```

**Edit:**

.NET int64 format is a number of ticks since midnight 0001-01-01 00:00:00 (every tick is 1/10000000 of second) and UNIX timestamp is number of seconds since beginning of the UNIX epoch (1970-01-01 01:00:00), so desired result is $seconds = 621355968000000000/10000000 - $number_of_seconds, see [Convert ticks to unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427493/convert-ticks-to-unix-timestamp) and https://kramerc.com/2010/11/30/converting-datetime-ticks-into-a-unix-timestamp-in-php/

Therefore, for JSON output you should do

```
$timestamp=1333699439;
$ticks = ($timestamp * 10000000) + 621355968000000000;
// outputs 634692962390000000
```

Test function php

```
function ticks_to_time($ticks) {
    return floor(($ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000);
}

$time = ticks_to_time(634692962390000000);
echo date("F j Y g:i:s A T", $time);
// outputs April 6 2012 4:03:59 AM EDT
```

Test function .net

```
Int64 intDate = 634692962390000000; 
DateTime dt = new DateTime(intDate); 
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString()); 
// outputs 4/6/2012 8:03:59 AM
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't have the access to .net application. I'll try giving "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z" format through json post and check if that works.

Comment: I checked and it responses with error. Saying "The value ''2012-04-06T08:03:59Z'' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int64'". I googled but couldn't find how to get time in int64

Comment: Since now you know that date is expected as an int64 value, you need to convert it as shown in updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer smirnov, I've got some really urgent work. So, can't even test this one. Will be checking tomorrow. I really appreciate it. Very very very thank you.