# How to get the unix timestamp in C#

Tags: c#, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have had look around stackoverflow, and even looked at some of the suggested questions and none seem to answer, how do you get a unix timestamp in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 734, accepted):

You get a unix timestamp in C# by using [`DateTime.UtcNow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow) and subtracting the epoch time of 1970-01-01.

e.g.

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
```

`DateTime.UtcNow` can be replaced with any `DateTime` object that you would like to get the unix timestamp for.

There is also a field, `DateTime.UnixEpoch`, which is [very poorly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.unixepoch) by MSFT, but may be a substitute for `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)`

Comment: Commenting on behalf of @wdhough. "This answer has limitation with the limit of Int32 which is, I believe, 2,147,483,647.  According to http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm this equates to a time of Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT

I guess any alternative number type, double, long, etc will ultimately have a limit too, but I thought it worth mentioning.  I choose long here as I wanted a whole number.  Hope this helps"

Comment: The unix timestamp is traditionally a 32 bit integer, and has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Comment: Or using integer arythmetic: `DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;`

Comment: The subtracted datetime does not need to be UTC?

Comment: @jjxtra DateTime does not care about the zone flag, and only takes into account the numbers when doing mathematical operations. DateTimeOffset is a smarter, and does take into account of the timezone flag. This is purposely done by .NET team.

Comment: The comment from @jjxtra seems correct to me and the given answer does not work in my case because DateTime(1970, 1, 1) is considered local time by the .NET Framework (I'm in UTC+1 zone).
So the timestamp I get is actually the current UTC Date minus the 1st january 1970 in UTC+1 : I get a one hour leap.
From what I understand, both date should be expressed with the same UTC offset so that this code works correctly.

Comment: The unix timestamp will suffer from a Y2K style problem in 2038: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: This answer is not the best (see the one from @rstackhouse below) and it is dangerous. Like it was already posted, this implementation will suffer from an integer overflow in the year 2038. I would not recommend to use it!

Comment: You are saving a timestamp in a type of Int32, this will potentially overflow

Comment: As for .NetCore 2.1 there is a new constant 'DateTime.UnixEpoch', so you can simply use the following code: 
var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;

Comment: the Armageddon is going to happen on 2038-01-19 at 03:14:08 precisely ;)

Comment: BTW: `DateTime.UnixEpoch` is defined to be in UTC. So ensure your variable is also in UTC (if you aren't simply using `DateTime.UtcNow`).  E.g., `someNotUtcDateTimeVariable.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds()`.

Comment: Check my answer from 2021 to avoid 2038 and use UTC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70372296/888472

Answer (score 969):

As of .NET 4.6, there is [`DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds`](//learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds).

---

This is an instance method, so you are expected to call it on an instance of
`DateTimeOffset`. You can also cast any instance of `DateTime`, though [beware
the timezone](//learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset). To get the current timestamp:

```
DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

To get the timestamp from a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
long unixTime = ((DateTimeOffset)currentTime).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

Comment: Until the [`Unix Millenium Bug`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) hits :)

Comment: @MattBorja Thankfully, it returns an `Int64` - by the time that rolls over, we'd not be using Earth years anymore for lack of an Earth.

Comment: @Ony, `DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc()` does **not** return the same as `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc(v=vs.110).aspx), “A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).”

Comment: You can get the UTC unixtimestamp with: DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()

Comment: @Lost_In_Library: it is AN answer, but not THE answer, as not everybody uses 4.6 (or is able to use, for whatever reason)

Comment: Oneline for those who want to modify the current date: `DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(365).ToUnixTimeSeconds()`

Comment: I want my date-time to be 10days ago, and using the above came up with this:       long initialUNIXTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-10).ToUnixTimeSeconds();        // i.e. DateTimeOffset has a Now() method of its own, so no need to involve DateTime class.

Comment: @MattBorja no, it returns a long, not an int

Comment: Note: Now vs UtcNow does not matter here - "This method first converts the current instance to UTC before returning its Unix time". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds

Answer (score 54):

You can also use Ticks. I'm coding for Windows Mobile so don't have the full set of methods. [TotalSeconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) is not available to me.

```
long epochTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;
long unixTime = ((DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - epochTicks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
```

or

```
TimeSpan epochTicks = new TimeSpan(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks);
TimeSpan unixTicks = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks) - epochTicks;
double unixTime = unixTicks.TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Error for the second solution: Cannot convert source type 'double' to target type 'long'.

Comment: @Pixar: The second sample is fixed

Comment: `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)` creates a time with unspecified `Kind` property. What you really want to `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)` to be truly correct

Comment: From .NET Core 2.1 You can use DateTime.UnixEpoch instead of new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.unixepoch?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 35):

With .NET 6.0, and using `long` to avoid the `2038` problem:

**From DateTime.UtcNow to UnixTime**

```
long seconds = (long)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
```

`seconds` will contains the seconds since 01/01/1970 (UnixTime)

**From UnixTime to DateTime.UtcNow**

```
DateTime timestamp = DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(seconds);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xNhO6q

Comment: Why do this over the `ToUnixTimeSeconds`/`FromUnixTimeSeconds` methods that already exist?

Answer (score 34):

This is what I use:

```
public long UnixTimeNow()
{
    var timeSpan = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
    return (long)timeSpan.TotalSeconds;
}
```

Keep in mind that this method will return the time as Coordinated Univeral Time (UTC).

Comment: (TotalSeconds has `double` type; casting it to long will cause loss of precision.)

Comment: You right, but we don't have to worry about that for several thousand years :)

Answer (score 30):

Truncating `.TotalSeconds` is important since it's defined as `the value of the current System.TimeSpan structure expressed in whole fractional seconds.`

And how about an extension for `DateTime`? The second one is probably more confusing that it's worth until property extensions exist.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a given DateTime into a Unix timestamp
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">Any DateTime</param>
/// <returns>The given DateTime in Unix timestamp format</returns>
public static int ToUnixTimestamp(this DateTime value)
{
    return (int)Math.Truncate((value.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds);
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets a Unix timestamp representing the current moment
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ignored">Parameter ignored</param>
/// <returns>Now expressed as a Unix timestamp</returns>
public static int UnixTimestamp(this DateTime ignored)
{
    return (int)Math.Truncate((DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds);
}
```

Comment: Extension method is clearly the way to do this neatly.
This is an excellent, mature answer - and i don't understand why it has so few votes.

  Pretty sure that Robba is correct - casting the output as (int) automatically truncates the result.  (Literally ignoring the decimal part of the double).

Comment: (this DateTime ignored) is very, very misleading

Comment: I like the first extension. The second is just a utility method, doesn't deserve to be an extension.

Comment: Note that `int32` will fail to cover timestamps beyond `19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT` due to it's integer size limitation.

Answer (score 13):

Updated code from Brad with few things:
You don't need Math.truncate, conversion to int or long automatically truncates the value.
In my version I am using long instead of int (We will run out of 32 bit signed integers in 2038 year).
Also, added timestamp parsing.

```
public static class DateTimeHelper
{
    /// <summary>
     /// Converts a given DateTime into a Unix timestamp
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="value">Any DateTime</param>
     /// <returns>The given DateTime in Unix timestamp format</returns>
    public static long ToUnixTimestamp(this DateTime value)
    {
        return (long)(value.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a Unix timestamp representing the current moment
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ignored">Parameter ignored</param>
    /// <returns>Now expressed as a Unix timestamp</returns>
    public static long UnixTimestamp(this DateTime ignored)
    {
        return (long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a local DateTime based on provided unix timestamp
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timestamp">Unix/posix timestamp</param>
    /// <returns>Local datetime</returns>
    public static DateTime ParseUnixTimestamp(long timestamp)
    {
        return (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).AddSeconds(timestamp).ToLocalTime();
    }

}
```

Comment: It should be `AddMilliseconds` for the `ParseUnixTimestamp(..)` method. Not `AddSeconds`

Comment: I saw timestamps in seconds and in other places in milliseconds, though usually when we talk about Unix timestamp, we talk about seconds. This version is in seconds as in most places.

Answer (score 6):

When you subtract 1970 from the current time, be aware that the timespan will most often have a non zero milliseconds field. If for some reason you are interested in the milliseconds, keep this in mind.

Here's what I did to get around this issue.

```
 DateTime now = UtcNow();

 // milliseconds Not included.
 DateTime nowToTheSecond = new DateTime(now.Year,now.Month,now.Day,now.Hour,now.Minute,now.Second); 

 TimeSpan span = (date - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0));

 Assert.That(span.Milliseconds, Is.EqualTo(0)); // passes.
```

Answer (score 5):

Below is a 2-way extension class that supports:

- Timezone localization
- Input\output in seconds or milliseconds.

In OP's case, usage is:

```
DateTime.Now.ToUnixtime();
```

or

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixtime();
```

Even though a direct answer exists, I believe using a generic approach is better.
Especially because it's most likely a project that needs a conversion like this, will also need these extensions anyway, so it's better to use the same tool for all.

```
    public static class UnixtimeExtensions
    {
        public static readonly DateTime UNIXTIME_ZERO_POINT = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a Unix timestamp (UTC timezone by definition) into a DateTime object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">An input of Unix timestamp in seconds or milliseconds format</param>
        /// <param name="localize">should output be localized or remain in UTC timezone?</param>
        /// <param name="isInMilliseconds">Is input in milliseconds or seconds?</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DateTime FromUnixtime(this long value, bool localize = false, bool isInMilliseconds = true)
        {
            DateTime result;

            if (isInMilliseconds)
            {
                result = UNIXTIME_ZERO_POINT.AddMilliseconds(value);
            }
            else
            {
                result = UNIXTIME_ZERO_POINT.AddSeconds(value);
            }

            if (localize)
                return result.ToLocalTime();
            else
                return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a DateTime object into a Unix time stamp
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">any DateTime object as input</param>
        /// <param name="isInMilliseconds">Should output be in milliseconds or seconds?</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static long ToUnixtime(this DateTime value, bool isInMilliseconds = true)
        {
            if (isInMilliseconds)
            {
                return (long)value.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(UNIXTIME_ZERO_POINT).TotalMilliseconds;
            }
            else
            {
                return (long)value.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(UNIXTIME_ZERO_POINT).TotalSeconds;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be careful not to confuse the milliseconds and seconds formats (best case is an exception, worst is illogical conversion)

I've defaulted the input\output to the milliseconds format. If you prefer to use the seconds format as default, just switch the isInMilliseconds=true (in both methods) to false.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use.

```
 public class TimeStamp
    {
        public Int32 UnixTimeStampUTC()
        {
            Int32 unixTimeStamp;
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime zuluTime = currentTime.ToUniversalTime();
            DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            unixTimeStamp = (Int32)(zuluTime.Subtract(unixEpoch)).TotalSeconds;
            return unixTimeStamp;
        }
}
```

Comment: perhaps make it an extension method of DateTime

Answer (score 4):

With  **NET 8**

You have this other option as well to get the timestamp with the new [TimeProvider Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeprovider?view=net-8.0)

```
 var timestamp = TimeProvider.System.GetUtcNow().ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've spliced together the most elegant approaches to this utility method:

```
public static class Ux {
    public static decimal ToUnixTimestampSecs(this DateTime date) => ToUnixTimestampTicks(date) / (decimal) TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
    public static long ToUnixTimestampTicks(this DateTime date) => date.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - UnixEpochTicks;
    private static readonly long UnixEpochTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work better to get the unix timestamp from any DateTime object. I am using .net Core 3.1.

```
    DateTime foo = DateTime.Now;
    long unixTime = ((DateTimeOffset)foo ).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a ToUnixTimeMilliseconds for DateTimeOffset in System

You can write similar method for DateTime:

```
public static long ToUnixTimeSeconds(this DateTime value)
{
    return value.Ticks / 10000000L - 62135596800L;
}
```

10000000L - converting ticks to seconds

62135596800L - converting 01.01.01 to 01.01.1978

There is no problem with Utc and leaks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391011/explain-tounixtimemilliseconds#58391256

Answer (score 0):

I used this after struggling for a while, it caters to the timezone offset as well:

```
    public double Convert_DatTime_To_UNIXDATETIME(DateTime dt)
    {
        System.DateTime from_date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
        double unix_time_since = dt.Subtract(from_date).TotalMilliseconds;

        TimeSpan ts_offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);

        double offset = ts_offset.TotalMilliseconds;

        return unix_time_since - offset;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UTC TimeStamp` as a `long` in `Tick` form there is an even faster shortcut for this.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert Ticks to Unix Timestamp
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="time"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static long ToUnixTimestamp(long time)
        {
            return (time - 621355968000000000) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

The simple code that I am using:

```c#
public static long CurrentTimestamp()
{
   return (long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds * 1000);
}
```

This code is giving unix timestamp, total milliseconds from **1970-01-01** to now.