# Convert unix time to specific datetime format with culture info

Tags: c#, string, datetime, converters

I try to to convert string to specific datetime format.

I have string:

```
1431075600
```

and I try convert this by:

```
private static IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
model.DeliveryDate = DateTime.Parse(data.DeliveryDate, culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

I got error message:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Finally I want to have datetime in format like

```
Friday, 8 May 2015 hour: 09:00
```

Comment: What datetime format your input string is using? I assume it's Unix timestamp? Then you can find the answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17632585/860913

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string looks like a [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is elapsed as a seconds since `1 January 1970 00:00 UTC.`. That's why, you can't *directly* parse it to `DateTime`. You need to create a unix time first and add this value as a second.

That's why you need to add your string as a second to this value like;

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
dt = dt.AddSeconds(1431075600).ToLocalTime();
```

And you can format your string after that with an *english-based* culture line [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx);

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dddd, d MMM yyyy 'h'our: HH:mm",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Result will be;

```
Friday, 8 May 2015 hour: 09:00
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VGw5MD)</kbd>.