# How to get datetime difference in double value using Timespan?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-format, data-conversion

I want to save `DateTime` difference in sqlserver database as a `double` value
but using `Timespan` I get only hour. I want to get it **hh.mm** format.

My code is as follows :

```
DateTime starttime = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
DateTime endtime = Convert.ToDateTime(date2);
TimeSpan span = endtime.Subtract(starttime);
double timedeff=span.Hours;
//Here I getting only hour.I want to this in 'hh.mm' format(double)
```

Comment: `hh.mm` is not a `double` format. It is a formatted `TimeSpan`. Can you please example of `starttime` and `endtime` with expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the unix timestamp in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp)

Comment: How could this be related @ckruczek?

Comment: @Rohit: I thought this question is coming. I was just thinking of the difference he needs. And I think, a unix timestamp difference is more accurate than a float number.

Comment: I dont hink you can judge like that, without know the exact requirements or reasons behind OPs scenario. @ckruczek there is also No reason for OP to use UNIX timestamp difference instead of DateTime difference.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want it in floating point format, e.g. xx.yy where yy = 0..60 right? So you get 10.02 which means 10:02.

The solution is easy:

```
DateTime starttime = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
TimeSpan diff = Convert.ToDateTime(date2).Subtract(starttime);

double timedef = diff.Hours + diff.Minutes / 100.0;
```

Otherwise this will do

```
double timedef = diff.Hours + diff.Minutes / 60.0;
```

I imagine it can have some use if you do something like this:

```
var str = timedef.ToString("0.00");
```

... but there are better ways to do that. TimeSpan and DateTime do a lot of magic, if you don't really need a `double`, stick with it until the very end.

**A note about fixed point**

DateTime uses integers to do its math. Double's use floating point. Floating point arithmetic by definition introduces errors; therefore it's probably better (and safer) to use integer arithmetics.

DateTime and Timespan provide exactly this for date and delta-time operations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted the difference to be in hours, convert minutes and seconds also into hours.

```
double timediff=span.Hours + span.Minutes/60.0 + span.Seconds/(60.0*60.0);
```

Comment: Why not just do span.TotalSeconds() * 3600 ? Then you also get the millis etc? PS: there's also an error in your (integer) division

Comment: @atlaste: sorry, for the division error. thanks. Thanks also for `TotalSeconds()`: I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what do you mean by

> 'hh.mm' format(double)

Assuming it to be something like :

> 9hrs 10 minutes = 9.10

```
   DateTime starttime = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
   DateTime endtime = Convert.ToDateTime(date2);
   TimeSpan span = endtime.Subtract(starttime);
   var datetime = new DateTime(span.Ticks).ToString("H:mm");
   string datetimestring = datetime.ToString().Replace(":",".");
   double timeinDouble =  double.Parse(datetimestring, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

*Here is a Sample Project if you want to test different scenarios - [LINK](http://goo.gl/VdwXD7)*

**Note :**

1. Be sure to use a "H", not "h", as a format specifier, otherwise an hours value of 0 might be printed out as "12".
2. If an elapsed time is e.g. 26 hours long, it prints out as "02:00" hours.
3. This method will cause problems if the timespan is negative.

Comment: It's incorrect; different locales give different results.

Comment: @atlaste - Could please expand?

Comment: `double.Parse("12.12")` -- in the Netherlands this gives 1212, in the UK this gives 12.12. A separator token is part ot the localization / cultureinfo; as such you should either not use it for literal representations or fix it manually (e.g. using an explicit CultureInfo). Once you do that, your implementation will be correct - but also pretty bad performance-wise.

Comment: A very valid point. i was thinking on localization issues related to Time.