# Convert DateTime to number format

Tags: datetime

What kind of DateTime format is this?

```
start_time=1467320400&end_time=1469998800
```

it should be start_time = 1.7.2016, end_time = 3.7.2016 (if not mistaken)

how from my c# code I can generate a DateTime in for format above?

Comment: If I interpret the numbers as unix timestamp, I get 30.06.2016 and 31.07.2016 at 9:00 pm. Are you sure that they should refer to 1.7.2016 and 3.7.2016?

Comment: I assume you are right, any idea how to convert it from c#?

Comment: I'm not using C# a lot. I think you should find a answer when you search for "C#" and "unix timestamp". I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17632584/4967497) for the other way around at the first rank on Google. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/249760/4967497) was the second result.