# Creating unique ID's for temporary textboxes

Tags: c#, html, textbox, unique, generated

I'm pretty new in the programming world and having a problem with ID's in my application. I have a database with ships and for every ship in the database, my code will create a div with a textbox (where i want to put the name of the ship that comes from the database). But every textbox has to have a unique ID to write data to it from the database.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv =
            new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createDiv.ID = "createDiv";
            this.Controls.Add(createDiv);

            TextBox tb_name = new TextBox();
            tb_name.ID = **"CreateT1";**
            createDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
            ("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' ></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'> Schipnaam: <input type='text' **id='CreateT1'** runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
```

The ID of the textbox isnow CreateT1, but i want it to be unique and generated. I have heard that my options are: Guid.NewGuid().ToString(n) or auto increment but i have no idea how to use them.

Hope you guys have the answer or other options!

Comment: You could use the [unix timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp) as the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a quick and temporary fix, try using the increment value `i` itself, since it iterates over all your database rows, so it will definitely be unique.

If you have other textboxes, or you want an alternative way, try setting a simple global variable `private int idCounter = 0;` and then every time you make a new textbox, you set its `ID` to `idCounter`, and call `idCounter++;` immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

> Guid.NewGuid().ToString(n) or auto increment

**Guid.NewGuid()**

```html
createDiv.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
tb_name.ID= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

**Auto increment via index**

```html
createDiv.ID = "createDiv-" + i;
tb_name.ID = "createTextBox-" + i;
```

Hope it helps.