# Generating HMAC-SHA256 Signature in C# from a Python sample

Tags: c#, python, signature, hmac

I've been trying to generate HMAC-SHA256 signature using three parameters; a Unix timestamp in seconds, an API Key and an API Secret, in C#.Net for authentication in a spesific style, but couldn't manage to reverse-engineer the steps from an example code in Python.

**The Python code I'm trying to dechiper the steps from is:**

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import datetime
import json

def create_signature_Py27(key, secret):  # (string key, string secret) 
    timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())  # UNIX timestamp in seconds
    string = "{}{}".format(timestamp, key)
    return hmac.new(secret, string, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# Python 2.7 - 3.5+ 
# Note: latest versions of hmac lib requires 'secret' and 'string' as byte strings but not unicode
#
def create_signature(key, secret):  # (string key, string secret) 
    timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())  # UNIX timestamp in seconds
    string = "{}{}".format(timestamp, key)
    return timestamp, hmac.new(secret.encode(), string.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

def auth_request(key, secret):
    timestamp, signature = create_signature(key, secret)
    return json.dumps({'e': 'auth',
        'auth': {'key': key, 'signature': signature, 'timestamp': timestamp,}, 'oid': 'auth', })

auth_request = auth_request('1WZbtMTbMbo2NsW12vOz9IuPM', '1IuUeW4IEWatK87zBTENHj1T17s'):
```

**What I've tried so far:**

```
       public static string TEST(string timestamp4, string apikey1, string apisecret1)
       {

     
           HMACSHA256 hmc1 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apisecret1));
           string mes = timestamp4 + apikey1;
           MessageBox.Show(mes);

           byte[] hmres1 = hmc1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mes));
           string hex1 = BitConverter.ToString(hmres1).Replace("-", string.Empty);
           string b641 = Convert.ToBase64String(hmres1).Replace("=", "");
           MessageBox.Show(b641, "b64");
           return b641;                   // THIS TEST SIGNITURE RETURNS SOMETHING LIKE "asdaefcdvcxv/sdfdsfsd/fsd" , WHERE DOES THE "/" COMES FROM?
                                         //TIMESTAMP RETURNS WRONG VALUE WHICH THEN FEED INTO SIGNITURE FUNCTION- GIVING INVALID SIGNITURE( but its unix timestamp in sec's whish is expected)
}
```

But with this, I cannot re-generate the correct sample signature. The Sample Apikey,Secret,timestamp and their product signature:

- **apiSecret**    1IuUeW4IEWatK87zBTENHj1T17s
- **timestamp**    1448034533
- **apiKey**   1WZbtMTbMbo2NsW12vOz9IuPM
- **signature**    *7d581adb01ad22f1ed38e1159a7f08ac5d83906ae1a42fe17e7d977786fe9694*

Instead, the signature I end up with is:

- **Generated Signature** 3EHLmGeh0jK9vRLgh/0j5LgQU6h/nijzj4G9KBBjv10

I have tried to feed the parameters one by one to the encryption function but that didn't go well.

When I use the *real function* to generate a signature with the real Api Key and Secret and realtime timestamp, the returned message from the server shows that timestamp is incorrect(but I couldn't see any problem), and that is also feed into the signature, which could have been solely due to the incorrect timestamp but even with the provided sample ApiKey and Secret, *the test function* generates entirely different structure.(with "/" in it and shorter)

There is no problem so far with the Json request function, but, just in case, this is what it should look like(the signature given her differs from the above):

**{
"e": "auth",
"auth": {
"key": "1WZbtMTbMbo2NsW12vOz9IuPM.",
"signature": "02483c01efc26fac843dd34d0342d269bacf4daa906a32cb71806eb7467dcf58",
"timestamp": 1448034533
}
}**

I apologize in advance if I missed any existing topics explaining this problem, and I'd greatly appreciate if someone could shed some light on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method returns the base64 representation of the signature.

If you return `hex1` instead, you get the expected result in upper case. If you want lower case letters, return `hex1.ToLower();`

Comment: Thank you, lowering did the job but timestamp is still returning error and therefore the signature is invalid.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp for the timestamp, You didn't post your logic of how you get the timestamp, so I can't tell you what's wrong with that.

Comment: found the problem.a typo in the json class...turned out there was a problem with the json