# Convert DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) to a unix timestamp using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, unix, timestamp

I've been searching all over and cannot find a single solution that seems to do what I need, all of them are for a specific date and I need to dynamically subtract days only.

This is my current code:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

The `.ToString("M/d/yyyy");` part is what I'm currently using to convert to a human readable date. I need to get the DateTime into a unix format.

Any help or suggestions on this would be great, thanks!

Comment: In what way does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760 not answer your question? When you say all of the other solutions are "for a specific date" I doubt that they're really hard-coded to a particular date. Note that using `DateTime.Now` is a *really* bad idea here though... you almost certainly want `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: How does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/250400/1141432) not help?

Comment: I'm not trying to convert a unix timestamp to datetime. I'm trying to convert a DateTime to unix timestamp. There has to be a simple way to just convert `Datetime.now` to a unix timestamp.

Comment: There is an answer in that thread linked by @itsme86 that converts a DateTime to a Unix timestamp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp

Comment: And there's this one... https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125275/converting-the-datetime-to-and-from-unix-epoch-times