# Convert current date and time into timestamp object (13 digits)

Tags: c#

The following is the code for converting java datestamp (13digits) to date (`1520488577604` to `3/12/2018 8:07:02 PM`) in C#.

```
new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    .AddMilliseconds((long)value) // put your value here
    .ToLocalTime().ToString("g");
```

I need to reverse this feature, need to convert from `3/12/2018 8:07:02 PM` to `1520488577604`.

Comment: You need in C#, correct?

Comment: Yes in C# I need this feature

Comment: check answer below. Let me know if you need anything more in it

Comment: Give few mins, i will try your answer

Comment: This is a classic UnixTimestamp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp

Comment: Are you sure about the exact values? 1520488577604 should be somewhere around 2018/03/08 05:56:17+0000

Comment: It is not an exact value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though Gavin and Gaurang are pretty close, they missed a detail: You wanted the total **milliseconds** from 1970/01/01

```
namespace MyApp.Extensions
{
    public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {
        public static long MillisecondsTimestamp(this DateTime date)
        {
            DateTime baseDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            return (long)(date.ToUniversalTime()-baseDate).TotalMilliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like

```
using MyApp.Extensions;

// ...
var millisecondsTimestamp = DateTime.Now.MillisecondsTimestamp();
```

given that you've added the namespace the `DateTimeExtensions` is located in.

Comment: thanks for drawing my attention.

Comment: @GaurangDave What exactly do you mean?

Comment: to use TotalMilliseconds.

Comment: @GaurangDave Ah, got it. I thought that it would've been clear from the comments to your answer :)

Comment: You mentioned my name in your answer then I saw comments and got my mistake. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'MillisecondsTimestamp' and no extension method 'MillisecondsTimestamp' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did you put `MillisecondsTimestamp` in a static class? Is the namespace included?

Comment: @SreejithSree Please see my edit.

Comment: I Add class keyword for DateTimeExtensions

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

10 digits:

```
public static long ConvertToTS(DateTime datetime)
{
    DateTime sTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc);

    return (long)(datetime - sTime).TotalSeconds;
}
```

13 digits:

```
public static long ConvertToTS(DateTime datetime)
{
    DateTime sTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc);

    return (long)(datetime - sTime).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Comment: The output of this function is a 10 digit number(1520939407),I need a 13 digit number.  I am calling this function like this: ConvertToTS(DateTime.Now) and date stored in db is 2031-01-12 18:18:11.421

Comment: why down vote? are yo getting 1520939407 this for 2031-01-12 18:18:11.421 ?

Comment: I am not put downvote, someone else do that

Comment: I downvoted. As the asker stated, he needs the full 13 digits, you're giving him 10.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I edited. And if possible, wait for final conclusion. I will also take care. remove down vote if possible.

Comment: @SreejithSree check update

Comment: The downvote prompted you to improve your answer, it served its purpose. I'll not wait, thanks. Though I did remove it once updated.

Comment: This gives wrong values unless `datetime` is in UTC anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

[How to get the unix timestamp in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Getting a 10 dig long value, for me need a 13 digit timestamp

Comment: The last 3 digits are milliseconds, do they really matter..

Comment: Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalMilliseconds;

Comment: @Gavin, yes? The requirement is to take 13 digits, get to a date, and then get the 13 digits back as entered.

Comment: Double unixTimestamp = (Double)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalMilliseconds;

Comment: Gives you 13 digits, plus a fraction...