# How I can convert a DateTime with timezone to a Unix TimeStamp ? C#

Tags: c#, datetime, unix

This is the code I got running:

```
string dateStart = "2020-03-03T20:12:15+00:00"
DateTime Start = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStart, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", null);
long unixStart = ((DateTimeOffset)Start).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

Then it crash, this is the exception:

```
Excepción producida: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' en System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' en System.Private.CoreLib.dll
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Convert to UTC and subtract `DateTime.UnixEpoch`?  `long unixStart = (long)Start.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;`

Comment: @mm8 please don't post answers in comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the unix timestamp in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp)

Comment: this code cannot run because its missing ; in first line.. if added the code perfectly runs fine in .net core console app with result : 1583266335.. so kindly post the exact code you are using plus which .net framework or .net core you are using

Comment: @HanyHabib I wrote the string here so I missed the ; but doesn't matter, it gives the exception there. Im using .NET CORE 3.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont know how to convert it @mm8

Comment: thats weird i ran the same example in .net core 3.1 also console app and it ran and i posted the result to:1583266335.. can your provide the whole piece of code.. as it should be working fine ..

Comment: @unknownJavi: See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert to UTC and subtract `DateTime.UnixEpoch`:

```
string dateStart = "2020-03-03T20:12:15+00:00";
DateTime Start = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStart, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

long unixStart = (long)Start
    .ToUniversalTime()
    .Subtract(DateTime.UnixEpoch)
    .TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, conversion was done but all milliseconds are like this:
`-62135596800 = Fri Jan 12 1968 20:06:43` |||||

`2020-03-01T21:00:00+00:00` that was the string I inputed.

Comment: @unknownJavi: No, the code above gives `1583266335` and nothing else. Try to copy and paste it into your IDE:

Comment: @mm8 this is the same value i posted up with his same code .. are you facing the same exception if you used his code ?..