# How to get Unix time stamp in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I have encountered following function in C# code:

```
Byte[] GetUNIXTimeStamp(DateTime dtVal)
{
  if (m_bytTimeStamp == null) m_bytTimeStamp = new Byte[14];

  Byte[] bytVals = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)dtVal.Day);
  m_bytTimeStamp[0] = bytVals[0];
  m_bytTimeStamp[1] = bytVals[1];
  bytVals = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)dtVal.Month);
  m_bytTimeStamp[2] = bytVals[0];
  m_bytTimeStamp[3] = bytVals[1];
  bytVals = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)dtVal.Year);
  m_bytTimeStamp[4] = bytVals[0];
  m_bytTimeStamp[5] = bytVals[1];
  bytVals = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)dtVal.Hour);
  m_bytTimeStamp[6] = bytVals[0];
  m_bytTimeStamp[7] = bytVals[1];
  bytVals = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)dtVal.Minute);
  m_bytTimeStamp[8] = bytVals[0];
  m_bytTimeStamp[9] = bytVals[1];
  bytVals = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)dtVal.Second);
  m_bytTimeStamp[10] = bytVals[0];
  m_bytTimeStamp[11] = bytVals[1];
  bytVals = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)dtVal.Millisecond);
  m_bytTimeStamp[12] = bytVals[0];
  m_bytTimeStamp[13] = bytVals[1];

  return m_bytTimeStamp;
}
```

…and just wondering if there is some shortest and cleanest way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Probably this [question][1] might help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 15):

you can use the following:

```
long CurrentTimestamp = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: I guess `DateTime.UtcNow` is the correct choice.

Comment: Doesn't `TotalSeconds` return a double value?

Comment: this has been answered on SO multiple times, and still you got it wrong :) you must use DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc) or daylight saving in some timezones will cause wrong results

Comment: Not beautiful but the idea is here:

`string timestamp =
                            ("" +
                             (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds)
                                .Split('.').First();`

Comment: For getting that I now use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Only available on .NET 4.6 and up.