# How should we parse a specific JSON date format in the ASP.NET C# application?

Tags: c#, json, date, json.net

We are using a third-party vendor for one of our modules in an application
The Web Service Endpoints are provided by a third-party vendor.

For one of the Web Service Endpoints that deals with posting Comments,

our ASP.NET C# web application will get back some JSON data.

I am using James Newton-King Json.NET for processing JSON data.

Within the JSON Data that we receive from the Web Service of the 
third-party vendor, we get the following date which is associated 
with time that the comment was posted:

```
\"date_created\": 1375206707,\r\n
```

Therefore, I created an ASP.NET DataContract C# class that would 
correspond to the JSON data that we are receiving.

Furthermore, I have the following DataMember in the C# class 
that would correspond to the date of creation associated with
the Posted Comment:

```
[DataMember(Name = "date_created")]
public string CommentCreationDate { get; set; }
```

Please make suggestions as to how I should parse the following JSON date format

in the ASP.NET C# world( possibly also involving the James Newton-King Json.NET):

```
\"date_created\": 1375206707,\r\n
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

// ( [How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa) )
// "UTC does not change with a change of seasons, but local time or civil time may change 
// if a time zone jurisdiction observes daylight saving time (summer time). 
// For example, UTC is 5 hours ahead of (that is, later in the day than) local time on 
// the east coast of the United States during winter, but 4 hours ahead while daylight saving is observed there."

// The following expects the reader.Value to be a Unix TimeStamp

```
        return (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by creating a custom *converter*.

```
string json = @"{""date_created"":1375206707}";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TempClass>(json,new DateConverter());
```

---

```
public class TempClass
{
    public DateTime date_created;
}

public class DateConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds((long)reader.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@I4V  Thanks for your help.

Since, I already using James Newton-King Json.NET technology to place the creation date in a string-based DataMember called CommentCreationDate, I include the following C# code to get the DateTime value.

CommentCreationUTDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(Int64.Parse(CommentCreationDate)).ToUniversalTime();

Comment: Why do you *place the creation date in a string-based DataMember called CommentCreationDate* ? My answer shows  how to get the **Datetime** value directly into a DateTime property

Comment: @I4V Thanks for pointing out my mistake.  Only now do I know that TempClass was an ASP.NET C# DataContract class.