# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: 筛

Tags: json, encoding, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am returning Chinese characters from Web Api and following code used to parse the response.

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        string tempString = null;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(endpoint);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = method;
        var inputSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        var outputSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T[]));
        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        inputSerializer.WriteObject(requestStream, pun);
        requestStream.Close();

        var response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream resstream = response.GetResponseStream();

        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            count = resstream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            if (count != 0)
            {
                tempString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buf, 0, count);
                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0);
        {
            //Response.Write(sb.ToString() + "<br/><br/>");
            // string[] val = sb.ToString().Split('"');
        }



        if (response.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            response.Close();
            return default(T[]);
        }

        T[] responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(sb.ToString());
```

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: 筛
It works fine for ENGLISH but not for Chinese.
I am sure it's encoding issue. Need help

I refereed [Unexpected character encountered while parsing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259173/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value) but no clue

Answer (score 1):

I built a quick sample test with a Web API controller that would return some Chinese string, and use a changed version of your client code to read the response.

The response was indeed garbage characters when using Unicode encoding. Changing it to UTF8 as shown below fixed the problem.

```
tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, count);
```

Note that most of times, the encoding for XML/JSON is UTF8 unless the service is really doing some Unicode (UTF16 Little Endian)