# How to parse json from html page?

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I want to get a web page (it is a server), on which there's information in json format.

I get the said page and if I check variable called json, I see that it contains correct json text.

The question is: **how do I parse this JSON information**?

**Details:** I have a WPF app, where I want to have some info from JSON in a Text Block when I press a button - but not everything but, for example, only one field. Also, I can't copy the code in file in advance because webpage is being updated and I need to load it every other time.
This code gets the page and JSON code:

```
  private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var json = webClient.DownloadString((My_Url));
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject o = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
            json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(webClient.DownloadData(My_Url));
            List1.Text = json.ToString();

        }
    }
```

This is sample json code:

```
{ "response": { "status": {"ok", "data": { "30" : {"title":{ "London", "Country": "Britain"}, "24": {"title":"Paris", "Country": "France"} }}
```

So I'd like to see in my listbox a list of "London, Paris"

Comment: Can you post a sample of the json you're trying to parse?

Comment: @DStanley yes I will tomorrow, now I can't access this server

Comment: Looks like you are downloading the same data twice? And if you get a JObject, you can inspect and get data from that.

Comment: @crashmstr I don't know how to get this data

Comment: `List.Text = (string)o["property1"]["childProp"]`? [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (you found enough of this information for get the `JObject.Parse(json)`)

Comment: @crashmstr so in TextBlock I will see only those fields of json which I have enlisted?

Comment: Read through the examples in the link from my previous comment, then if you still have a question, 1. show the exact JSON data 2. the code you have tried.

Comment: @crashmstr if I understood correctly these examples, I should have a json code in advance, but it is loaded from the page. I want this loaded code be transformed into classes automatically like if I would have done using Edit-special paste-paste json as classes

Comment: @NickShepard If the data changes randomly each time you request it, good luck. Otherwise, get it, save it, look at it (and even paste it JSON -> class and deserialize it that way). You *need* to know something about what you are looking for in advance, or you need to be really good at fuzzy searching the data.

Comment: @crashmstr I know how the properties(fields) are called, but content may be different from request to request, So, I need to deserialize my variablr called json?

Comment: @NickShepard if it varies on each request and you can't show me the two or three forms it might take, there is no way *I* can help. You would need to iterate over the deserialized content and try and find what you are looking for. But it sounds like this is a very poor API.

Comment: @crashmstr okay, tomorrow morning I will add to my question sample of json code

Comment: @NickShepard and to clarify: I'm talking about the *structure* and *organization* of the json changing, not the *value* contained within. I would expect the *values* to change over time. If you know the structure, everything is easy (download it, paste json as class, and deserialize to that).

Comment: @crashmstr I've edited my question

Comment: @crashmstr this is the question - how to paste it as class and then deserialize

Comment: @DStanley I've added sample json

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to Deserialize that json.

```
List1.Text = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have an exception "unexpected valid encountered while parsing value

Comment: that error is thrown when you don't pass a json to json deserializer, look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259173/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value

Comment: what advice should I use? I tried to implement File.ReadAllText, but then there's an exception that URI is not supported. So now I want listbox to show list of "titles" of my json (London and Paris)

Comment: Firstly, which is the flow? What do you want to do?

Comment: Answered in previous comment

Comment: Ok, you need to see how looks that json and create a class after that json, after that you need to deserialize with that class or list of that class, depends on json.

Comment: is of possible to create these classes automatically, not manually? That somehow it is created by itself

Comment: I think no... but you could try something like this:

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string,List<string>>>>(json);

Comment: exception:cannot deserialize current json object into type system.collections.generic

Comment: okay I created class Cities with property title, what should I do to enlist cities in listbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150917/discussion-between-alex-and-nick-shepard).