# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'Data', line 1, position 26

Tags: c#, asp.net

While I am trying to parse the Json Result I get following exception:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'Data', line 1, position 26.

Here is My Json Data:

```
{
   "StatusCode":200,
   "Data":[
      {
         "MemberId":1,
         "CreaterUserId":5,
         "FirstName":"Saravanan",
         "LastName":"Subramanian",
         "Title":"Physician\u0019s Assistant",
         "License":"A 123447",
         "Email":"saravanan.radhamani@gmail.com",
         "PhoneNumber":"1234567",
         "IsSign":true,
         "IsMemberActive":true,
         "CreatedDate":"2018-06-23T15:45:44.843",
         "PhotoPath":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is My C# Code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string response = null;
    try
    {
        response = makeRequest();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PolstForm>(response);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("StatusCode : {0} , Data : {1}",
               data.StatusCode,
               data.Data[0]));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string makeRequest()
{
    var client = new RestClient(urlString);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
    return client.Execute(request).Content; //the Content (body) of the response
}
```

This is My PolstForm.class

```
public class PolstForm
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

When I am trying to parse the data from json it returns an Error.

Error Shown is:

> JsonReaderException is unhandled by user code :
>   **An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [.
>   Path 'Data', line 1, position 26.**

response contains above Json format.

If you have alternate thing please share with me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected character encountered while parsing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259173/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value)

Comment: Are you sure that you've presented the ***actual*** JSON being parsed? What you've shown doesn't have a position 26 at line 1.

Comment: The json looks fine. Did you copy it from `response` as it is or did you alter it? You may have removed some characters which create the issue ...

Comment: Now I am Edit my code and add PolstForm class please tell me a solution. parse a null value error..from a PhotoPath thats I think.

Comment: `string Data` and your Json shows an array here instead of a string. Also what do you expect `data.Data[0]` to return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PolstForm` class doesn't match your Json's structure.

I would've written it this way for example:

```
public class PolstForm
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public CustomData[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class CustomData
{
    public int MemberId {get;set;}
    public int CreaterUserId {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string License {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
    public bool IsSign {get;set;}
    public bool IsMemberActive {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get;set;}
    public string PhotoPath {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rafalon I am Already found the answer in a similar way as your code..  I just taken the class as list for ex of your code .. List<CustomData> customData; Thank u for taking a time to think a solution for me.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As you know, 
the json String can't parse to a String data;  [public string Data { get; set; }]

```
 [
   {
     "MemberId":1,
     "CreaterUserId":5,
     "FirstName":"Saravanan",
     "LastName":"Subramanian",
     "Title":"Physician\u0019s Assistant",
     "License":"A 123447",
     "Email":"saravanan.radhamani@gmail.com",
     "PhoneNumber":"1234567",
     "IsSign":true,
     "IsMemberActive":true,
     "CreatedDate":"2018-06-23T15:45:44.843",
     "PhotoPath":null
  }
```

]

Comment: I'm facing same problem. It's coming from Asp.Net Core after parsing of data. You can do string manipulation here. I did it worked.