# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path '', line 0, position 0. Does not update the entity in the database

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When updating an entity in the database, it throws an exception.

"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path '', line 0, position 0."

```
 public void UpdateMainEditor(Photogallery entity)
        {

             _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Unable to update entity and save it
after SaveChanges() gives an exception at endpoint

Endpoint Put

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromODataUri]int key, [FromBody] Photogallery oData)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (key != oData.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            try
            {
                await _targetHelper.Update(oData, User);

                return Ok(oData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
            }
}
```

Model Photogalleries

```
public class Photogallery : IBaseEntity<int>, ITargetItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Multilingual]
        [Required, StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Multilingual]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime PublicationStart { get; set; }
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
        public bool IsGroup { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual List<PhotogalleryFile> Files { get; set; }

        public virtual List<TranslatePhotogallery> TranslatePhotogalleries { get; set; }
    }
```

Model TranslatePhotogallery

```
 public class TranslatePhotogallery
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int PhotogalleryId { get; set; }

        public TranslateLanguage Language { get; set; }

        public string TranslateField { get; set; }


        public virtual Photogallery Photogallery { get; set; }

    }
```

TranslateLanguage is enum!!!! In database nvarchar! :D

Body in request

```
{
    "id": 46,
    "name": "Test Postman 2, 3,4",
    "description": "Text",
    "publicationStart": "2019-03-22T08:49:46.981Z",
    "companyId": 4,
    "isGroup": true,
    "translatePhotogalleries": [{
        "language": "Ukrainain",
        "translateField": "Some Text"
    }]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? [Unexpected character encountered while parsing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259173/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value)

Comment: @TylerRoper, I do not want to use DeserializeObject. Updates should occur without explicit deserialize.

Comment: There are other answers/solutions there besides the one that's accepted, noting that this error occurs if the JSON is malformed or incorrect. Perhaps you can share your JSON.

Comment: @TylerRoper, look at the description of the problem. There in API there is a check on ModelState.IsValid. І in the description there is also JSON.

Comment: I have tried to invoke from POSTMAN and there is't any trouble with request model, just to make sure did you set content type for your request?

Comment: @H.Herzl, type content is application/json.

Comment: It seems like an encoding trouble, did you check this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7188 ?

Comment: @H.Herzl, Some entities I have updated in the database without problems, but the problem with the essence of the photo galleries!

Comment: In that case I'll need to replicate the same models in order to debug the exception, by the way, did you checked the required attributes for model properties? The error messages seems like there was an exception to cast, I have tried in my workstation and there is no trouble with request

Comment: Hey, check you URL, maybe you have an invalid URL, it should be Photogallery/46, can you show your HttpPut attribute for action please?