# Visual studio 2019 not show error - break mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Good afternoon,

I am trying to correct an error in my program, but VS is not using the error line at all

I already know why the API token is expired, so I wanted to know the exact line for me to handle it

I have already activated and deactivated "just my code", "symbols" ... but nothing has worked yet.

[Error from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRAYD.png)

I use "using Newtonsoft.Json;"
Has anyone ever experienced this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not deserializing the JSON correctly. Look at your object at wherever you're deserializing and check the layout of the object matches the JSON. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259173/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value

Comment: Thanks "li223", I saw the link sent. But in the case VS doesn't show me the line with the error, it just launches this screen (print). How do I get the error exactly? Other errors it shows the exact line, I had never seen this :(

Comment: You'll have to debug your code and run through where you're deserializing json and see where the program breaks and throws the error. This will also let you make sure you're actually getting the JSON you're expecting.

Comment: Understand,
I went with "f10"
But I still didn't find the line, there are some "async await"
Apparently it is in these sections, but as I was not seeing the line it was complicated.
But I know the error as I said. Since the token is expired (this is why the json does not come correctly), I did a check before (I know that the token expires in 30 days), then with 29 days passed I am sending the person to the login screen

Thanks for trying to help, thanks.