# Is there a way to prevent Unexpected character that was encountered while parsing from JSON to C# and XAML error?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I was working on my project and I've come across this error that makes me abit frustrated for no reason:

[TheProblem][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ajtn.png

I have been looking for many ways to solve this even on this very website but none worked so far for C# and Xaml. I am attempting to get JSON files into UPF to look like GUI.

My Vehicle Class:

```
    public class Vehicle
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("make")]
        public string Make { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("VIN")]
        public string VIN { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("CarType")]
        public string CarType { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("Seatingcapacity")]
        public int Seatingcapacity { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("DateObtained")]
        public string DateObtained { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("NumOfMiles")]
        public int NumOfMiles { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("InspectionNum")]
        public int InspectionNum { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("InspectionTech")]
        public string InspectionTech { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("InspectionDate")]
        public string InspectionDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("InspectIssues")]
        public string InspectIssues { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("RepairDiscard")]
        public string RepairDiscard { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("EstPrice")]
        public int EstPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("EstimatedBy")]
        public string EstimatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("EstimatedDate")]
        public string EstimatedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("SalePrice")]
        public int SalePrice { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("SalesPerson")]
        public string SalesPerson { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("SalesDate")]
        public string SalesDate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("NegotiatedPrice")]
        public string NegotiatedPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("NegotiatedPriceApproved")]
        public string NegotiatedPriceApproved { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Vehicle")]
        public List<Vehicle> Vehicle { get; set; }
    }
    public class VehicleManager
    { 

        public static async Task<Root> GetVehicles()
        {
            string target = "Vechile.json";

            Root vehicleJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(target);

            return vehicleJson;
        }

    }
```

My Vehicle JSON:

````
    {
      "make": "Audi",
      "model": "A4",
      "vin": "1B4HR28N41F524347",
      "carType": "Sedan",
      "Seatingcapacity": 4,
      "DateObtained": "05/15/2010",
      "NumOfMiles": 434567,
      "InspectionNum": 312345,
      "InspectionTech": "Windows",
      "InspectionDate": "06/05/2016",
      "InspectIssues": "No Issue",
      "RepairDiscard": "No Discard",
      "EstPrice": 700000,
      "EstimatedBy": "Sannaha Vahanna",
      "EstimatedDate": "04/27/2010",
      "SalePrice": 500000,
      "SalesPerson": "Sannaha Vahnna",
      "SalesDate": "05/15/2010",
      "NegotiatedPrice": "$45,000",
      "NegotiatedPriceApproved": "Sannaha Vahnna"
    }
}```
As well, my C#

```public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
           var Vehicles =  VehicleManager.GetVehicles();
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void VehicleGUI_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var vehicle= (Vehicle)e.ClickedItem;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(VehicleDetails), vehicle);

        }

    }```

What to do?
````

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message it's giving you. It says the unexpected character is 'V' at line 0 position 0. My guess is the data being passed is not actually the JSON data you think it is - perhaps it's some kind of string representation of a `Vehicle` (only guessing on that part from the 'V').

The best way to troubleshoot is throw your data being serialized into a local variable and set a break point right before you call the method to serialize. That way you can see exactly what is getting passed.

You may actually want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23259173/15744261), you may be having a similar issue.