# Sending a string array as part of a HTTP Get request

Tags: c#, http, xamarin

I've created the following function to send an object via a HTTP GET request.

```
    public async Task<string> Get<T>(T item, string path, string authorisationToken = "")
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

        var query = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);

        httpClient = new HttpClient();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authorisationToken))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
              new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authorisationToken);
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(path, query));
        HttpContent Content = response.Content;
        var json = await Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        response.Dispose();
        return json;
    }
```

While this works great for sending basic classes, it falls over if the class has anything like an array.

For example, sending instances of this class works fine;

```
public class MySimpleClassWithNoArray
{
    public int page { get; set; } = 1;
    public string searchKey { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

But trying to send an instance of this class falls over because the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject function fails;

```
public class MySimpleClassWithAnArray
{
    public int page { get; set; } = 1;
    public string searchKeys[] { get; set; }
}
```

How can I improve on this function to cater for arrays and possibly other types?

Comment: Please show code that attempts to deserialize into `MySimpleClassWithAnArray` and include the specific error message.

Comment: how does string array appear when you use it in the browser?  Whatever works there you should be able to replicate when building your request url in code

Comment: Hi @Jason, in JSON format this would be something like { "searchKeys" : ["text1", "text2"] }

Comment: Hi @NoahStahl, the error message is "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'searchKeys', line (line no.), position (position no.)'

Comment: That's not what I asked.  A GET is just a normal browser request.  What querystring would you use in a browser to pass your array to the server?  Whatever you do in the browser you would replicate in your code.

Comment: Ah yes apologies @Jason, here is what works in the browser: "mywebsite/myAPI/v1/groups?searchKeys=text1,text2". That however is not how I want to use it, I would like to pass the searchKeys text as part of the JSON body.

Comment: if you want to pass a JSON body, use POST.  That's not how GET works.

Comment: @Jason I am interfacing to a Wordpress BuddyPress API to perform a GET request. It accepts a JSON body as part of the request. But that is a moot point, this is an absolutely valid method to perform a GET request. My function works fine, I just want to make it cater for arrays.

Comment: Hi  @KDev, have you checked this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for `Deserialize` to work, The class shall be as below.

```
public class MySimpleClassWithAnArray
 {
     public int page { get; set; } = 1;
     public SearchKeys SearchKeys { get; set; }   // modify this line
 }
 
 public class SearchKeys   // add this class
 {
     public string[] Keys {get;set;}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this however the parsing still fails with a slightly different error to before: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'searchKeys', line (line no.), position (position no.)"

Comment: As per the error, it seems that either its not a valid json or the model is not correct

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259173/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value)

Comment: Hmm well I suspect it has more to do with with this line "var query = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);". Because I want to split the object from a class to a parameterized query to place into the request, it works fine for non-array field since the JSON deserialize is able to convert it, but it is not able to convert an array (or a class, like you described in your answer).