# How do I make a MVC to convert C# object to json and send it to client, and receive json and convert it to a C# object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to a make an MVC (but without the view), that sends and receives json objects, but the objects it sends are first in C#, and the objects it recieves in json have to be converted to C# objects.  I have very little knowledge of json, and not much knowledge of using C# in this manner, but I have taken a crack at it by first creating two classes in the model folder (or partially creating), one called SendData, the other called ReceivedData, and defining the variable types of the object that will be converted into json or from json.

Description of system:
Have an MVC that gets data from an SQL database, converting the C# object into a json, and sends the json to a client app.  Client app sends a different json to MVC that needs to be converted into a C# object which is used to update database (or is a request for an update from database).

The MVC will recieve json that contains several variables and a list of items (of the same type).  It will send a json that contains several variables, and a list of objects/data contained in multiple objects (eg: ObjectListName:[ {variable1fromobject1:data, varibale2fromobject1:data, variable3fromobject1:data} {variable1fromobject2:data, variable2fromobject2:data, variable3fromobject2:data}] )

How do I set this up for the conversion of received data to C#, and conversion of data to be sent into json?

Comment: Sounds like you want [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) instead.

Comment: No, I mean the technology.

Comment: You need a Json serializer. Like Json.NET or ServiceStack.Json

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebAPI.  Is it a framework like ASP.NET?

Comment: I have experience with sending and receiving jsons with MVC, best way for my opinion is to use Json.Net (Newtonsoft.Json). You can install it from Nuget or to get dll from here http://james.newtonking.com/json. With help of this JSON framework you can easily convert received string into c# object and c# object to serialize to json and then return as Content(...);

Comment: Found a problem json.net .  It doesn't seem to parse unix time formats (long int), instead I found it only uses IsoDateFormat or MicrososftDateFormat

Comment: Also json doesn't support long int :(

Answer (score 2):

Newtonsoft Json.NET would help you a lot :)

http://james.newtonking.com/json

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);

Comment: Wow.  That looks like it could be really useful.  Will try it out.

Comment: one problem.  json.net doesn't seem to support unix time format.

Comment: @cluemein - see here: [How to deserialize a unix timestamp (ms) to a DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971494/how-to-deserialize-a-unix-timestamp-ms-to-a-datetime)

Comment: Ok, the code to deserialize, would that go in the controller or with the model classes?

Comment: One option would be to add that as a new class, perhaps in a common location within your solution. It would be potentially called and reused by multiple controllers.