# Date Time format issue in crunchbase API using C#

Tags: c#, json, api

I am working in crunchbase api. I have got result form Crunchbase api https://developer.crunchbase.com/docs. I did not able to parse given value of Created date and update date to Datetime format using C#
[image]

anybody help me to fix this issue ??

Answer (score 1):

Those numbers are unix timestamps.

Lucky for you, conversion is pretty straightforward since they just represent the time passed in seconds since 01.01.1970

```
// create a new DateTime for the time timestamps start counting from 
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dtDateTime = dt.AddSeconds(myJson.created_at).ToLocalTime();
```

Where `myJson.created_at` is your extracted date time.

Now that you realize what these attributes *are*, consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19971494/1348195) and answers that explain how to convert a unix timestamp to a C# datetime automatically as part of JSON conversion. Note that question is kind of different, you want seconds and not milliseconds like in that answer.