# Convert UNIX-Time to DateTime when Deserializing with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, unix, datetime

In the JSON objects that is returned from the API I'm using, it returns the time in Unix-format with "time" as key:

```
time = 1434810953
```

Using the JSON.Net

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
```

I want to automatically convert the unix-timestamp to a DateTime for my object

```
Public DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971494/how-to-deserialize-a-unix-timestamp-ms-to-a-datetime, only it looks like yours may be in seconds not ms, so see https://stackapps.com/questions/1175/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-net-datetime