# Using Newtonsoft.Json, what's the backing field for a property in a getter

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to deserialize and serialize a unix timestamp to a DateTime, what's the backing variable name that I should use in the getter?  I'm using the standard Microsoft ToDo quickstart with Xamarin.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "date")]
public DateTime Date
{
    get
    {
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(WHATGOESHERE).ToLocalTime();
        return dtDateTime;
    }
    set => ((DateTimeOffset)value).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
}
```

Comment: You need to use classic property with explicit backing field.
The backing field cannot be referenced if you use automatic property.

Comment: will that automacially still work with the newtonsoft JSON?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey Json.NET only cares about the property; what your code does *inside* that doesn't concern it. Slight caveat there: if you have a get only automatically implemented property (`public DateTime Date {get;}`) - many serializers will know how to store to that value by using internal Roslyn details

Comment: So I guess the part that I'm a bit confused about is to make sure it is stored in the database as a unix timestamp - if I create the backing variable, will it serialize to a DateTime to store in the JSON - I need it to be a unix timestamp in the JSON.  I think I'm assuming a lot of Newtonsoft magic here which might not be the case.

Comment: You could also bind this json value to property of type `long`,
And use another get-only property which converts this timestamp to actual `DateTime`.

Comment: yeah that seems like a simpler plan than creating a json serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using "automatically implemented properties" (i.e. `{get;set;}`), then the backing field is **whatever you create**. It isn't done by the compiler. So: declare a field and use that.

Note that your `set` doesn't actually assign the computed value to anything currently - it just does the math and drops the value on the floor. That *also* needs to assign to the backing field.

I'll be honest though; I'm not sure why this isn't just:

```
[JsonProperty("date")]
public DateTime Date {get;set;}
```

It *looks* like you're trying to convert it such that it is `DateTime` in the serialization but epoch seconds inside the type. That sounds... unusual and odd. If you really want that, though, just declare an integer (`long`, presumably) for your field, and read/write accordingly.

Comment: in the json it's a unixtimestamp and in the class I want it to be a DateTime - I want it to stay a unixtimestamp in the Cosmos database

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey k; you're doing it backawards, then; the good news is you don't need to do *anything* here - this is simply a Json.NET configuration setting... one moment while I look it up

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey edit: huh, my bad - Json.NET only supports ISO and MS - I must have been thinking of JIL (anther JSON serializer); but: see this question for ways to do it in Json.NET via custom serializers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971494/how-to-deserialize-a-unix-timestamp-%CE%BCs-to-a-datetime (adjust the code shown to use seconds, obviously)

Comment: Ah ok - I was mistakenly assuming some magic happens in the getter setter with Newtonsoft.