# Deserialise Json Timestamp with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, datetime, system.text.json

I am trying to deserialise the following JSON

```
{"serverTime":1613967667240}
```

into an object of the following class

```
public class ApiServerTime
{
    [JsonPropertyName("serverTime")]
    public DateTime ServerTime
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

with the following command:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ApiServerTime>(jsonString);
```

but the resulting object contains the `ServerTime == DateTime.MinValue`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize a unix timestamp (μs) to a DateTime from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971494/how-to-deserialize-a-unix-timestamp-%ce%bcs-to-a-datetime-from-json)

Comment: @KenTsu I found that but it's related to Newtonsoft.Json. I am using System.Text.Json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can register custom date formatters for System.Text.Json also.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support

```
public class DateTimeConverterForCustomStandardFormatR : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(reader.GetInt64());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // The "R" standard format will always be 29 bytes.
        Span<byte> utf8Date = new byte[29];

        bool result = Utf8Formatter.TryFormat(value, utf8Date, out _, new StandardFormat('R'));
        Debug.Assert(result);

        writer.WriteStringValue(utf8Date);
    }
}


string js = "{\"ServerTime\":1613967667240}";
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverterForCustomStandardFormatR());
var value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ApiServerTime>(js, options);
```

Answer (score 6):

In the spirit of building a better mouse trap, here's an implementation that supports..

- Unix time in seconds OR milliseconds based on whether the value in seconds can represented within .net DateTime min/max range (1/1/0001 to 31/12/9999).
- Nullable DateTime to gracefully cater for invalid, empty, and null values.

```
public class UnixToNullableDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime?>
{
    public bool? IsFormatInSeconds { get; init; }

    public override DateTime? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        try
        {
            if (reader.TryGetInt64(out var time))
            {
                // if 'IsFormatInSeconds' is unspecified, then deduce the correct type based on whether it can be represented as seconds within the .net DateTime min/max range (1/1/0001 to 31/12/9999)
                // - because we're dealing with a 64bit value, the unix time in seconds can exceed the traditional 32bit min/max restrictions (1/1/1970 to 19/1/2038)
                if (IsFormatInSeconds == true || IsFormatInSeconds == null && time > _unixMinSeconds && time < _unixMaxSeconds)
                    return DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(time).LocalDateTime;
                return DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(time).LocalDateTime;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // despite the method prefix 'Try', TryGetInt64 will throw an exception if the token isn't a number.. hence we swallow it and return null
        }
        
        return null;
    }

    // write is out of scope, but this could be implemented via writer.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds/WriteNullValue
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime? value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    private static readonly long _unixMinSeconds = DateTimeOffset.MinValue.ToUnixTimeSeconds(); // -62_135_596_800
    private static readonly long _unixMaxSeconds = DateTimeOffset.MaxValue.ToUnixTimeSeconds(); // 253_402_300_799
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- according to [What is the “right” JSON date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/what-is-the-right-json-date-format)  you had better to use ISO 8601

```
"\"\\/Date(1335205592410)\\/\""         .NET JavaScriptSerializer
"\"\\/Date(1335205592410-0500)\\/\""    .NET DataContractJsonSerializer
"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"              JavaScript built-in JSON object
"2012-04-21T18:25:43-05:00"             ISO 8601
```

- you also can use JsonMicrosoftDateTimeConverter to deserialize it. but it need change json presentation. your can reference the link [System.Text.Json DateTime & DateTimeOffset “/Date()/” serialization](https://blog.macrosssoftware.com/index.php/2020/02/20/system-text-json-datetime-datetimeoffset-date-serialization/)

```
{
    "Date": "\/Date(1580803200000-0800)\/"
}
```

- at last, you can use temporary model to save current timestamp, then convert it.

```
public class ApiServerTime{
public long ServerTime{get;set;}
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime( double unixTimeStamp )
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds( unixTimeStamp ).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation from [Microsoft's page on the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support), where date is in the format `{"serverTime": "/Date(1590863400000)/"}` or `{"serverTime": "/Date(1590863400000-0700)/"}`:

```
sealed class UnixEpochDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    static readonly DateTime s_epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    static readonly Regex s_regex = new Regex("^/Date\\(([+-]*\\d+)\\)/$", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        string formatted = reader.GetString()!;
        Match match = s_regex.Match(formatted);

        if (!match.Success
            || !long.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out long unixTime))
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        return s_epoch.AddMilliseconds(unixTime);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        long unixTime = Convert.ToInt64((value - s_epoch).TotalMilliseconds);

        string formatted = string.Create(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, $"/Date({unixTime})/");
        writer.WriteStringValue(formatted);
    }
}
```