# why c# doesn't show the changes in variable?

Tags: c#, variables, precision

I'd tried this code  by these values:

```
float timeStamp;
a=1338526801      
    b=113678

 timeStamp = a +( b / 1000000);
```

then I changed the  `b` to `113680` and calculated the timeStamp,

```
timeStamp = a+ (b / 1000000) ;
```

in real the timeStamp should change because the `b` has been changed, but when  I print it by console.writeline(), the timeStamp value doesn't change.I think it refers to the precision of the c# values, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: No, you didn't try that code because that doesn't even compile. Please post the actual code you have. Your question/issue is also pretty unclear, please be more clear about what you're trying to do, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.

Comment: so use a `double` which is more precise.

Comment: Use `DateTime.Seconds` or convert a `DateTime` to Ticks. floats/doubles are inherently inaccurate. Wikipedia surely has a good explanation of the IEEE floating point standard if you want to know why.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to parse `Unix Time`. Here's how you do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20796273/885318

Comment: No,I don't want to convert time, you can suppose the ts_sec and ts_usec as some usual variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Floating-Point Types Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949.aspx) which gives the following info

```
> Type       Approximate range      Precision 
> float      ±1.5e−45 to ±3.4e38    7 digits
> double     ±5.0e−324 to ±1.7e308  15-16 digits
```

Your combination of `338526801` + `113678`/1000000 is about 16 digits and would better fit into a double.

A float which contains 7 digits would get you accuracy to 338526800.000000 and no more

```
float f = 338526801 + 113678f/1000000
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(f.ToString("F6")); // results in 338526800.000000
```

however a double gets 15-16 digits can actually store the data to your precision.

```
double d = 338526801d + 113678d/1000000
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(d.ToString("F6")); // results in 338526801.113678
```

You could also look at [`Timespan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz841zbz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `DateTime` which give you accuracy to 100-nanosecond units.  Since there are 10 ticks in a micro-second (us), the same TimeSpan would be:

```
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(3385268011136780);
```

One of the comments suggested you might be trying to convert Unix Time.  If so then you can add the Timespan to the proper DateTime representing 1/1/1970.

Comment: No, because it divides the ts_usec by 1000000 so, after changes in it's value may be it trucate the value so the timestamp value doesn't change, that is my problem

Comment: @marziyeesmslampanah I added some additional information that should help you understand the issue.

Comment: thanks alot,I think I should use the timespan or DateTime to solve my problem,but I don't know how should I define these types of variables.

Comment: I can solve my problems,by your advice.i change my program like this:  doube x=(double)y+double(y)/10000000