# Convert 10 digit Julian date to DateTime

Tags: c#

I tried to convert 1368463365 which is an int field in sql server database with the following code

```
public static DateTime JulianToDateTime(int julianDate)
{
    int RealJulian = julianDate + 1900000;
    int year = Convert.ToInt32(RealJulian.ToString().Substring(0, 4));
    int DoY = Convert.ToInt32(RealJulian.ToString().Substring(4));
    DateTime d = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    return d.AddDays(DoY - 1);
}
```

Comment: Define "Julian Date" here. It looks like you are referring to the text  representation of a mashed number since 1900 (which is not a [Julian Date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)).

Comment: Show sample input and expected output, or describe more precisely your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert UNIX timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a Unix timestamp there. The value 1368463365 would be equivalent with 13 May 2013 16:42:45 GMT.

A Unix timestamp is simply the number of seconds since midnight January 1st, 1970 UTC/GMT. So you can convert it to a regular `DateTime` like this:

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeToDateTime(long timestamp)
{
    var dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds((double)timestamp);
    dateTime = dateTime.ToLocalTime();  // Change GMT time to your timezone
    return dateTime;
}
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/250400/146622). Usage:

```
long timestamp = 1368463365;
Console.WriteLine(UnixTimeToDateTime(timestamp));
```

Result (on my Dutch computer, in UTC+2):

```
13-5-2013 18:42:45
```

Answer (score 3):

Your input is not a julian date. It's a timestamp. `1368463365` refers to `Mon, 13 May 2013 16:42:45 GMT`.

You can use following method to get `DateTime` from timestamp:

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime( int unixTimeStamp )
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds( unixTimeStamp ).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The number 1368463365 is [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and it's number of seconds since 1/1/1970. In that case what you have to do is to just add this timestamp to `DateTime` representing the the date 1/1/1970 00:00:00.

Example code from another SO question:

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime( double unixTimeStamp )
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds( unixTimeStamp ).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa) for reference.

And BTW, there's a little place for mistake here, but if you want to check what date such timestamp represents, you can check it online with [this converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Insofar as I know, *Julian Date* can mean

- The count of days since 1 January 4713 BCE at 12:00:00 pm (Noon) UTC in the Julian Calendar, which is 24 November 4714 BCE in the Gregorian calendar. Today 18 February 2014 is JD 2456706 (for at least part of the day.)
- The ordinal day of the year (e.g. 31 December 2013 is 2013365; 31 December 2012 is 2012366.

None of these are 10 digits. For conversion to/from the former, see http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/JD_Formula.php (your tax dollars at work...or at least **my** tax dollars at work).

Conversion to/from the ordinal date form should be pretty obvious:

```
string   julianDate       = "2014323" ; // the 323rd day of  2014
int      year             = int.Parse( julianDate.substring(0,4) ) ;
int      ordinalDayNumber = int.Parse( julianDate.substring(4,3) ) ;
DateTime dt               = new DateTime(year,1,1).AddDays( ordinalDayNumber - 1 ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The unix time is a the number of seconds since midnight January 1, 1970 UTC.

```
DateTime UnixTimeToDateTime(int timestamp)
{
    return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(timestamp);
}
```