# Convert Long to DateTime in Windows Phone C#

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8

I am getting requests from API for my app. In that the date/time is claimed to be in the format of Long. I am trying to convert it using the following lines.

```
DateTime? dt = new DateTime(long.Parse(detail.CREATEDTIME));
MessageBox.Show(detail.CREATEDTIME + "=>" + dt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

The actual output is as follows:

```
1393559958788=>0001-01-02
```

But the expected output is as follows:

```
1393559958788=>2014-02-28
```

The expected output is from java. How do i do this with `C#`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, the `long` value represents a [Unix Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa) for how to convert.

However, note that your values appear to be milliseconds since 1/1/1970, not seconds, so you may need to use .AddMilliseconds, rather than .AddSeconds,

The code I used to confirm this was:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1,0,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(1393559958788);
Console.WriteLine(d); // 28/02/2014 03:59:18
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(long.Parse(detail.CREATEDTIME)).ToLocalTime();
MessageBox.Show(detail.CREATEDTIME + "=>" + dt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```