# store minutes to database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, visual-studio-2012

hello i'm new to programming i have the following problem

```
string tt = drpPickuptime.SelectedItem.Text;            
DateTime mora = Convert.ToDateTime(tt);
```

I have also tried this

```
string tt = drpPickuptime.SelectedItem.Text;           
DateTime mora = DateTime.Parse(tt, new CultureInfo("fr-FR")).Date;
```

and this 1 also

```
DateTime mora = DateTime.ParseExact(drpPickuptime.SelectedItem.Text, "mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

but the error is nor rectified. The problem is that i have a combobox and i have put just minuts there which will be selected by user. I want to store that value in database. But in database the data type of that field is datetime. When i change that to string the problem is solved. But isn't it possible to store that string in database with required conditions. Though it is not a good question but i have done my all effort on it and could;nt get the result. Can anyone help me please

Comment: i have also tried many other ways to do that but it gives the same error every time, String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Well given *just* a minutes value, what `DateTime` are you trying to store?

Comment: i just want to store the minuts selected by user, these are 00, 15, 30, 45. I am not sure what should be the exact format for that.

Comment: Can't you do `mora.Minutes`? That retrieves the minutes property from your `DateTime` object. This will only work *given* your parsing is successful.

Comment: mora.minuts is not possible

Comment: @user3420100: If you're just trying to store minutes, you shouldn't be using a `datetime` field in the database.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: yup i also concluded this. But for more practice i asked this question to know whether it is really not possible or i am doing any mistake.

Comment: Well you can decide to set the minutes on some arbitrary date and time... but it's a really bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you cannot create a valid DateTime with just minutes, there needs to be a date (year, month, day).

If you are just storing minutes in the database then I would recommend an `int` type. If you really must have a DateTime then you will need to store a date too, perhaps Today's date is an option? in which case you can do this:

```
int minutes = int.Parse(drpPickuptime.SelectedItem.Text);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(minutes);
```

Comment: Precisely. Databases don't understand what `2014-03-11T02:00:00-07:00` means (you technically can store it as a string but the DB still doesn't know how to sort that given any situation you need to sort), which is why a common practice is to convert it to a unix timestamp and then store into a DB. Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Comment: @musefan: I have tried your solution it again gives the error "Input string was not in a correct format".

Comment: @user3420100: Please provide an example of your input string

Comment: @musefan: I have the follwoing code at frond end and back end
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="drpPickuptime"  Skin="Metro" AutoPostBack="true"
   runat="server"

   Width="100%"
  >
   <Items>
       <telerik:RadComboBoxItem  Text =":00"  Value="1" Selected="true"   />
      <telerik:RadComboBoxItem  Text =":15"  Value="2" Selected="true"   />
       <telerik:RadComboBoxItem  Text =":30"  Value="3" Selected="true"   />
       <telerik:RadComboBoxItem  Text =":45"  Value="4" Selected="true"   />


     
   </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>

Comment: int minuts = int.Parse(drpPickuptime.SelectedItem.Text);
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(minuts);
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =dt;

Comment: So the problem is your input is `":15"` so you need to remove that semi-colon (`:`) before you parse it to an int

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be to change the datatype to bigint, and store it as a timespan. You can store the Ticks property of the timespan in the database, then when you bring it back you just do `TimeSpan.FromTicks(database field)`. And to store it you can do `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(your comobobox value)`, you will have to parse the combobox value to an integer.

Comment: but the value come from combobox is string by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store minutes as a DateTime in the database, as @Jon mentioned. You'd have to store the value as an integer. Then if you want to apply those minutes to some date value, you could do:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(tt);
```

or if you want those minutes in the past you could do:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(tt * -1);
```

You could also store it in the database as a string. Then in your code you can do an int.Parse to convert it from a string to an integer.

Comment: You can also just do `-tt` to invert it