# DateTime to string parsing - Sort by year

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-formatting

I have an app which collects data from a `Google API`. When im sending a query to the API it only accepts date as string format `yyyy-MM-dd` and that's fine. For that reason I'm converting this DateTime variable to string format `yyyy-MM-dd` so the API accepts my request. I'm parsing DateTime to string as this will be a part of a large MVC application and I would like to stick with DateTime regarding data that concerns dates. In the case below `start` will return a date like eg: `2014-03-20` when I'm sending the request to the API.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter StartDate! (yyyy-MM-dd)");     
var start = Console.ReadLine();
var StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I would like to sort the dates that are returned by year, start will return StartDates as string yyyy-MM-dd from a list of dates. Somehow i need to apply some logic saying `yyyy = year`. Is there a standard procedure for this?

Comment: Are you sorting a collection of DateTime objects or a collection of strings?

Comment: its a collection of strings, simply a list of "Start" and "End" as strings.

Comment: If your are in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, you can just sort the usual way, this will sort by year, then by month, then by day

Comment: I am probably missing something but if you are just asking how to sort dates as string in yyyy-MM-dd format then just as Chris Ballard says sort them normaly like any of these.. http://dotnetfiddle.net/ELMJKe

Comment: Consider parsing the strings with your mentioned format, converting it to Unix Timestamps, and store. Much easier to sort this way. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa I personally use Jon Skeet's NodaTime library. It's a great tool, especially once you get into dates where it involves timezones, which the C# `DateTime` library begins to become *very* confusing.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - yes, but not relevant here. :)

Comment: @KristofferAndersson - You're making sense right up to "I would like to sort the dates..." - up till then, you have only shown code for taking a single date from your user.  What is it that you're *sorting*?

Comment: Alright, guess this would be fairly uncomplicated then. Thx