# Another data type to store date and time

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm creating a C# program that create a packet data. One of the data in the packet is the Date and Time of 4 bytes size. I did this:

```
 public byte[] convertDateTimetoHex4bytes(DateTime dt)
    {
        //Convert date time format 20091202041800
        string str = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
        //Convert to Int32 
        Int32 decValue = Convert.ToInt32(str);
         //convert to bytes
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(decValue);
        return bytes;
    }
```

However, it seems that I need to use 8 byte of data, since 32 bit is too small (error during run time). Anyone can help me, if there is any other smaller Date Time format with 4 bytes? or any other way?

Comment: Why do you need to convert to a byte array? What do you intend to do with the result?

Comment: What is the exact format or specification you're trying to follow? Why are you formatting the DateTime to a string like that?

Comment: Likely duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is logical as, the given string value when converted to a number, is simply [*too big*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) to be represented by Int32 and the extra information cannot be "shoved in".

```
20140616160000  -- requested number (i.e. DateTime for today)
    2147483647  -- maximum Int32 value (2^31-1)
```

---

A [UNIX Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) might work as is [traditionally] 32-bits, but it only has second precision and a limited range of 1970~2038. See [How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa) if interested in this approach.

The timestamp results in a smaller numeric range because it doesn't have unused numbers around the different time components; e.g. with the original format, numbers in the union of the following formats are not used and thus "wasted":

```
yyyyMMddhhmm60-yyyyMMddhhmm99   -- these seconds will never be
yyyyMMddhh60ss-yyyyMMddhh99ss   -- these minutes will never be
yyyyMMdd25hhss-yyyyMMdd99hhss   -- these hours will never be
                                -- etc.
```