# How to parse date format?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

In one of the webservices my application is consuming, I encountered the following DateTime format.

`"/Date(1395780377459)/"`

Is this some standard date format? If so, how to parse this into DateTime object?

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments. So `"/Date(1395780377459)/"` corresponds to GMT: Tue, 25 Mar 2014 20:46:17 GMT
. I was wondering how to parse this in .net. Tried:

```
         string test = "/Date(1395780377459)/";
         var datestring = test.Substring(6).TrimEnd(')','/');
         var date = new DateTime(long.Parse(datestring));
```

Tried this too:

```
 string test = "/Date(1395780377459)/";
 var datestring = test.Substring(6).TrimEnd(')','/');
 var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
 var result =  epoch.AddSeconds(long.Parse(datestring));
```

It doesn't work. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: You must be getting response in JSON format. This is JSON format for date

Comment: Refer `Roy Tinker's` answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-microsoft-json-date/2316066#2316066 question

Comment: @devnull: On SO, please always be more specific than just _"it doesn't work"_: Does that mean that the code does not compile? (If so, what compilation error do you get, and where?) Does is throw an exception at runtime? (If so, which one, and at which location?) Does it yield an unexpected result? etc.

Comment: @devnull, Most probably, your webservice returns a json and json serializers can handle it very well(for ex Json.Net). How do you *comsume* your json? I don't think you have to do some extra work to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a unix timestamp:

```
http://www.epochconverter.com/

Tue, 25 Mar 2014 20:46:17 GMT
```

In .NET:

```
var epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dt = epoch.AddMilliseconds(1395780377459);
```

(Source: [How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa))

Comment: Thanks. Got it working by adding milliseconds, instead of seconds

Comment: @devnull: Thanks, changed my answer. For some reason my LinqPad wouldn't accept AddMilliSeconds ;)

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do this? I mean a .NET supported way?

Answer (score 2):

I think the date is in milliseconds format. So you can try this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(long.Parse(1395780377459));
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");
```

or simply

```
var time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1395780377459);
```

Also the if the date is in json format then you may try this as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-microsoft-json-date/2316066#2316066):

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

Comment: I tried: `string test = "/Date(1395780377459)/";
         var datestring = test.Substring(6).TrimEnd(')','/');
         var date = new DateTime(long.Parse(datestring));`

Comment: @devnull:- Can you try this: var date = new Date(parseInt(datestring.substr(6)));

Comment: Thanks. Got it working by adding milliseconds, instead of seconds

Comment: @devnull:- You are welcome. I didnt get that very clearly. I mean you got it working after you divided the time by 1000 and then using Seconds?