# GroupWise 2014 Date Format to DateTime

Tags: c#, json, date, groupwise

I'm working with the GroupWise 2014 Rest API and I have a problem parsing their date format.

When you fetch a user you receive a json object with "timeCreated": `1419951016000`,

But I can't figure out what format that date is.

I've tried

```
DateTime.Parse
DateTime.FromFileTime
DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc
```

The value `1419951016000` should be around the time `2014-12-30 15:50`

Comment: have you consulted the API docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds since January 1st, 1970 at UTC.  Current unix time *in seconds* is [shown here as 1419964283](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/).

To convert to a `DateTime` to unix time, see here: [How to convert UNIX timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa).  That code works for unix time *in seconds*; the following works for unix time in milliseconds, represented as a `long`:

```
public static class UnixTimeHelper
{
    const long MillisecondsToTicks = 10000;
    static readonly DateTime utcEpochStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    static DateTime UtcEpochStart { get { return utcEpochStart; }}

    public static DateTime ToDateTime(long unixTimeInMs, DateTimeKind kind)
    {
        var dateTime = UtcEpochStart + new TimeSpan(MillisecondsToTicks * unixTimeInMs);
        if (kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
            dateTime = dateTime.ToLocalTime();
        return dateTime;
    }

    public static long ToUnixTimeInMs(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
            dateTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
        var span = dateTime - UtcEpochStart;
        return (long)(span.Ticks / MillisecondsToTicks);
    }
}
```

With this code. `UnixTimeHelper.ToDateTime(1419951016000, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString()` gives the value "12/30/2014 2:50:16 PM".  Is your desired value of "2014-12-30 15:50" in UTC or your local time?

If you are using Json.NET to serialize your JSON, you can write a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to do the conversion automatically from a `DateTime` property using the instructions here: [Writing a custom Json.NET DateTime Converter](http://cgeers.com/2011/09/25/writing-a-custom-json-net-datetime-converter/) .  That code also works for unix time in seconds and so will need to be tweaked.

(Finally, seconding Plutonix's suggestion to double-check the documentation.  In particular you need to read what the documentation says about the *time zone* in which the times are returned.  It's probably UTC but it pays to make sure.)

**Update**

After a quick search the [online doc](https://www.novell.com/documentation/groupwise2014/gwsdk_gwadminweb/data/bookinfo.html) looks pretty bad, but [this page](https://www.novell.com/documentation/groupwise2014/gwsdk_rest_api/application.htm#gw-api/domains) makes mention of

> expiretime
>   long
>   Optional. Use an explicit expiration cut-off time. The time is specified as a java long time.

[`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) represents "the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT" as a `long`.