# facebook v2.2 c# posts function oauthexception #100

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, posts

I need help to solve one of my Facebook problem. Below is the error I met:

[image: posts error]

I tried changing the limit from 5000 to 1000 to 25 to 10. But this error still exists. I've also checked that it is ";" and not ":". I tried changing whatever I could but to no avail. Can anyone help me with this???

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the problem is with `until` parameter that you passing in 
`fb.Get` method. as it states in the error message ensure that it has a correct representation ([unixtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa) or date/time format)

Comment: How do I ensure that it has the correct representation (unixtime or date/time format? I only have `string datetime = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now);` in my coding