# Load images with date criteria from Instagram

Tags: c#, instagram

I have this code which loads images from Instagram.

```
public string giveInstagramImage()
    {
        string strtagName = "Snowy";
        string strAccessToken = "<<REDACTED>>";
        string nextPageUrl = null;
        string imageUrl = null;
        do
        {
            WebRequest webRequest = null;
            if (webRequest == null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPageUrl))
                webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(String.Format("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{0}/media/recent?access_token={1}", strtagName, strAccessToken));
            else
                webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(nextPageUrl);

            var responseStream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encode))
            {
                JToken token = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
                var pagination = token.SelectToken("pagination");
                if (pagination != null && pagination.SelectToken("next_url") != null)
                {
                    nextPageUrl = pagination.SelectToken("next_url").ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    nextPageUrl = null;
                }
                var images = token.SelectToken("data").ToArray();
                foreach (var image in images)
                {
                    imageUrl = image.SelectToken("images").SelectToken("standard_resolution").SelectToken("url").ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl))
                        Console.WriteLine("broken image URL");

                    var imageResponse = HttpWebRequest.Create(imageUrl).GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

                    var imageId = image.SelectToken("id");
                    return imageUrl;
                }
            }
        }
        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPageUrl));
        return imageUrl;
    }
```

Currently Instagram API gives me the top 20 images. What I need to do is load all images from the last 30 days.

How can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Tag Endpoint](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) accepts a `count` parameter. If you set the `count` parameter greater than 33, it will return 33 images on every call and using the pagination you can continue to get the rest of the images.

```
webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(String.Format("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{0}/media/recent?access_token={1}&count=100000", strtagName, strAccessToken));
```

To load all images for the last 30 days, set `count` to a very high value and check `created_time` property of each image to stop wherever you like.

```
var imageCreatedTime = image.SelectToken("created_time");
```

Comment: I am getting time in some different format. How to get it in datetime format?

Comment: To convert it to datetime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Comment: so is instagram returning in unixtimestamp? didnt understood which example to use

Comment: Yes it is: UnixTimeStampToDateTime