# How to Convert unix Timestamp in nanoseconds to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, unix-timestamp

I have a C# WPF User Interface and c back end. I'm receiving unix Timestamp in nanoseconds from the back end. Is there any way to convert that nanoseconds to human readable format?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime( double unixTimeStamp )
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds( unixTimeStamp ).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

**[Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)**

Comment: Except the time stamp that the OP is receiving is in *nanoseconds*. You need to divide that value by 1,000,000,000 before calling `AddSeconds`.