# Parse timestamp to get all values

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a lot of data with timestamps in the following format: `20150603005845`. I need to parse this and turn it into `2015/06/03 00:58:45 AM`. I know I can convert it into a string and break it up and parse it the hard way but I was wondering if there are any inbuilt classes that can help me achieve this. I'm new to C# and don't know if there are any methods that can help me do this. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this might help? Just a quick search so I'm not sure how relevant it would be...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse date:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("20150603005845", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Format date:

```
string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss tt");
```