# timestap time used in instagram API in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timestamp, instagram-api

I've been cached response from instagram api.but response contains specular time format, that i didn't meet it anywhere.

```
"created_time":"1437648595",
```

and now my Question is:

How to convert it from this template (As String type) to System.DateTime type?
tanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram [uses](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/?hl=en) this value as a [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), you can get this as a `double` first and you can use it as ;

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
dt = dt.AddSeconds(1437648595).ToLocalTime();
```

It returns `23.07.2015 13:49:55` in my time zone which I currently in `UTC+03:00`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this post answers your question.
[How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

The format that you have posted looks like Unix time. Start your searching from there ;)